# How to cherry-pick multiple commits

Tags: git, git-rebase, cherry-pick

I have two branches. Commit `a` is the head of one, while the other has `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` on top of `a`. I want to move `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` to first branch without commit `b`. Using cherry pick it is easy: checkout first branch cherry-pick one by one `c` to `f` and rebase second branch onto first. But is there any way to cherry-pick all `c`-`f` in one command?

Here is a visual description of the scenario (thanks [JJD](/users/356895/JJD)):

[image: A commit showing a 'before' and 'after' state. In the 'before' state, commits a through f are connected in one contiguous sequence. In the after state, commits c through f have been relocated to directly connect to a without reordering, leaving the b commit behind.]

Comment: the rebase you mention is not really relevant for the question is it? (I get that you may want `b` to be based on `f` later on, but that has nothing to do with the cherry-picking.)

Comment: See also a sort of inverse corollary to this: [Revert a range of commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4991594/4561887)

Answer (score 2340, accepted):

Git 1.7.2 introduced the ability to cherry pick a range of commits. From the [release notes](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.2.txt):

> `git cherry-pick` learned to pick a range of commits
> (e.g. `cherry-pick A..B` and `cherry-pick --stdin`), so did `git revert`; these do not support the nicer sequencing control `rebase [-i]` has, though.

To cherry-pick all the commits from commit `A` to commit `B` (where `A` is older than `B`), run:

```
git cherry-pick A^..B
```

If you want to *ignore* A itself, run:

```
git cherry-pick A..B
```

Notes from comments:

- `A` should be older than `B`, or `A` should be from another branch.
- On Windows, it should be `A^^..B` as the caret needs to be escaped, or it should be `"A^..B"` (double quotes).
- In `zsh` shell, it should be `'A^..B'` (single quotes) as the caret is a special character.
- For an exposition, see [the answer by Gabriel Staples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69472178/4561887).

*(Credits to damian, J. B. Rainsberger, sschaef, Neptilo, Pete and TMin in the comments.)*

Comment: In the "cherry-pick A..B" form, A should be older than B. If they're the wrong order the command will silently fail.

Comment: If you have git 1.7.1 or earlier and can't update, you can pretty quickly cherry-pick them in order by running `git cherry-pick f~3` then `git cherry-pick f~2` etc. up to `git cherry-pick f` (pressing the up arrow gets the previous command so I can quickly change the number and run it, should be similar in most consoles).

Comment: It may be good to know that this syntax works with branch names too. `git cherry-pick master..somebranch` will pick all commits on somebranch since master (assuming is already rebased onto master), and apply them to your current branch.

Comment: I am getting conflicts while doing a `git cherry-pick A^..B`
I want to resolve all these conflicts **using theirs**. I tried
`git cherry-pick -X theirs A^..B`
Still getting conflicts

Any help ?

Comment: You can also do `git cherry-pick f~3 f` which will take commits from branch `f` and 3 commits before that (inclusive)

Comment: Is there a way to `cherry-pick` all commits for given file?

Comment: On Windows in cmd.exe, `^` is a special character and is silently ignored in `A^..B`. You have to double it (`^^`) or put the commit reference in quotes.

Comment: @VibhuDadhichi Try this: `git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs A^..B`

Comment: Note that `A^` is selecting one of A's parent commits. This means you have to be careful if it has multiple parent commits (e.g., it's a merge commit).

Comment: cherry-pick ... -n gives you the most control. It only stages, does not commit. So you can still look at what you are going to do.

Comment: Note 3 should be Note 0 :)

Comment: "A should be older than B" is not entirely correct. It picks everything from B that is not reachable from A, but A can be a different branch (with newer commits than in B), in which case everything that is in the B branch is picked.

Comment: This command didn't work for me in the console of GIT Extension (3.4.1.9675). Always picked the first commit and not the range ...

Comment: I just ran into an issue where this wasn't working with zsh because ^ is a special character in zsh. Wrapping the range of commits in singe quotes got this to work. 
`git cherry-pick 'A^..B'` https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/4398
The error I was seeing was "zsh: no matches found: A^..B"

Comment: I just [expounded upon the above answer in my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69472178/4561887).

Comment: That's strange but when I used double dots between the commits I got empty commits. Adding the third dot resolved the issue.
git cherry-pick A^...B. I was cherry-picking from the different origin. In other words I had to cherry-pick commits from other repository. Maybe this was the reason, no idea.

Comment: thank you! this has been a great answer!

Comment: @PrzemekNowicki, the difference between 2 dots and 3 dots is very significant. `git diff branch1...branch2` is the equivalent of `git diff $(git merge-base branch1 branch2) branch2`. This is useful when you want to see the changes that have been made in `branch2` since it diverged from `branch1`, rather than the differences between the two branches in their current states. See [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif/7252067#comment112851552_7252067)...

Comment: ...and the answers here: [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7251477/4561887)

Answer (score 242):

If you have selective revisions to merge, say A, C, F, J from A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J commits, simply use the below command:

```bash
git cherry-pick A C F J
```

Answer (score 145):

### How to cherry-pick a single commit, multiple commits, or a range of commits

**...onto your currently-checked-out branch:**

### 1. to cherry-pick a *single* branch or commit named `commit`

```bash
git cherry-pick commit
```

Examples:

```bash
git cherry-pick my_branch                                 # by branch name
git cherry-pick 1e038f108a130831f108329b1083a8139813fabc  # by full hash
git cherry-pick 1e038f10                                  # by partial hash
```

### 2. to cherry-pick *multiple* commits

Note that you can cherry-pick *any number of commit hashes* at once, and *in any order you want.* They will simply be applied one-at-a-time, and in the order you specify. If any conflicts arise, you will have to resolve them one-at-a-time then use `git add my_file` then `git cherry-pick --continue` when done to continue the cherry-pick process.

```bash
git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 commit3 commit4 commit5
```

### 3. to cherry-pick a *range* of commits

I originally learned the basics of this style from the [most-upvoted answer by @Eric Darchis here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933416/4561887).

Notice that to cherry-pick a *range* of commits, you must specify a starting and ending commit hash, with `..` between them. However, in a range of commits, the beginning commit is NOT included. Therefore, to include it, you must specify the commit *before* the beginning commit. The syntax to specify the *preceding* commit is to put `~`, `~1`, or `^` right *after* your commit, as in: `beginning_commit~`, which means: "the commit right before `beginning_commit`".

```bash
# A. INCLUDING the beginning_commit
git cherry-pick beginning_commit~..ending_commit
# OR (same as above)
git cherry-pick beginning_commit~1..ending_commit
# OR (same as above)
git cherry-pick beginning_commit^..ending_commit 

# B. NOT including the beginning_commit
git cherry-pick beginning_commit..ending_commit
```

*Note:* `commit~`, `commit~1`, and `commit^` all mean "one commit *prior to* `commit`", or otherwise said: "the commit before `commit`".

To specify *two* commits prior to `commit`, you can use syntax like this:

```bash
commit~~
commit~2  # my preferred syntax
commit^^
```

To specify *three* commits prior to `commit`, you can do this:

```bash
commit~~~  
commit~3   # my preferred syntax
commit^^^
```

This does NOT work:

```bash
commit^3   # INVALID syntax
```

This *does* work, but is a very special case. See also my Q&A: [In a `git merge`-style workflow, show only the unique commits someone had in their PR's (Pull Request's) feature branch before merging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77617436/4561887):

```bash
# valid on **merge commits** only
commit^2   # this is the immediate **right** parent of the two parents 
           # involved in the merge (which made commit `commit`)

# valid on any commits (gets the left parent of a merge commit, or 
# the only parent of a non-merge commit)
commit~    # and this is the immediate **left** parent of the two 
           # parents involved in the merge (which made commit `commit`)
```

To test the above "previous commit syntax" concepts yourself, the easiest way is with the `git log` command. Ex:

```bash
git log commit
git log commit~
git log commit~1
git log commit^
git log commit~~
git log commit~5
# etc.
```

### 4. To cherry-pick a range of your peer's commits onto your branch

...when their branch `peer_branch` is forked off of an earlier version of your branch `my_branch`.

#### Quick summary

```bash
# you cherry-pick all of their extra commits from their `peer_branch` onto 
# your `my_branch` (note: the 3 dots below are very important!)

git fetch origin peer_branch  # get their latest changes from the remote
git checkout my_branch        # ensure you're on your branch
# cherry-pick their range of commits
git cherry-pick my_branch...origin/peer_branch  
git log                       # review the commits you just chery-picked
git push                      # push your changes to the remote
```

The difference between 2 dots and 3 dots in a commit range is very significant. `git diff branch1...branch2` is the equivalent of `git diff $(git merge-base branch1 branch2) branch2`. This is useful when you want to see the changes that have been made in `branch2` since it diverged from `branch1`, rather than the differences between the two branches in their current states. See [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif/7252067#comment112851552_7252067) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits/69472178#comment137438679_3933416) and the answers here: [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7251477/4561887)

#### Full details and work-flow walk-through

Let's say you are working on your feature branch `my_branch`, and your peer wants to help make some changes for you to help you on your feature. You have already pushed `my_branch` to the remote named `origin`. So, they are going to fetch your remote branch named `my_branch` to their local computer, fork their own branch named `peer_brach` off of it, then push to their own branch named `peer_branch`. Once they do that, you will cherry-pick all of their additions at once. This is what the first part of this process looks like:

```bash
# **your peer** does this

# peer fetches your branch named `my_branch` and forks their `peer_branch`
# off of it

# they fetch your latest work from remote `my_branch` into their locally-stored
# remote-tracking "hidden" branch named `origin/my_branch`
# (note: you can see all locally-stored remote-tracking "hidden" branches
# with `git branch -r`)
git fetch origin my_branch
# create `peer_branch` as a fork off of `origin/my_branch`, and check it out
git checkout -b peer_branch origin/my_branch

# Now they can add their changes and commits and `git push` to remote `origin`
# as their own `peer_branch` when done.
```

Now that they have pushed all of their changes to remote `origin` as their own branch named `peer_branch`, you can cherry-pick *all* of their commits they added on top of your work like this:

```bash
# **you** do this to cherry-pick your peer's helpful changes they added to 
# your work

# you fetch their latest work from their branch named `peer_branch` on remote
# `origin` into your locally-stored remote-tracking "hidden" branch named 
# `origin/peer_branch` 
# (note: you can see all locally-stored remote-tracking "hidden" branches
# with `git branch -r`)
git fetch origin peer_branch
# ensure you are on `my_branch` (if you aren't already)
git checkout my_branch
# you cherry-pick all of their extra commits from their `peer_branch` onto 
# your `my_branch` (note: the 3 dots here are very important!)
git cherry-pick my_branch...origin/peer_branch

git log                       # review the commits you just chery-picked
git push                      # push your changes to the remote
```

For your understanding, that `cherry-pick` command just above, with 3 dots in it, is *exactly equivalent* to this longer command:

```bash
git cherry-pick $(git merge-base my_branch origin/peer_branch)..origin/peer_branch
```

The `git merge-base my_branch origin/peer_branch` part finds the common parent commit hash between branch `my_branch` and branch `origin/peer_branch`. This is the commit at which point they forked their `peer_branch` off your your `my_branch`. Then, you are, of course, cherry-picking the *range of commits* from that point to (`..`) their final commit at `origin/peer_branch`.

To read more about that 3-dot syntax, see here: [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7252067/4561887). For help on `git checkout -b new_branch from_branch`, see my answer here: [Various ways to create a branch in git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418267/4561887)

### Official Git documentation

1. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions - mentions git commit 3 dot (`...`) vs 2 dot range syntax, `^commit` ("not" `commit`), `commit^` (the parent of `commit`), etc.

### Going further

1. Something else to know: a `git rebase` is just a bunch of sequential `git cherry-pick`s. See my other answer here ([Who is "us" and who is "them" according to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63911630/4561887)) where I show, among other things, an ASCII drawing I made of how a `git rebase` works and what it's doing.
2. [What are the differences between double-dot ".." and triple-dot "..." in Git diff commit ranges? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7252067/4561887)
3. My answer on [Various ways to create a branch in git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418267/4561887)
4. My Q&A: [In a `git merge`-style workflow, show only the unique commits someone had in their PR's (Pull Request's) feature branch before merging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77617436/4561887)

Comment: Regarding: `commit~3   # my preferred syntax`
Perhaps it would be better to call it "revision" for consistency with git naming.

Comment: I agree with the `commit~3 # my preferred syntax`. It's one of the few things I can manage to remember `HEAD~1` is one commit back from `HEAD`. In the same concept I think `git cherry-pick beginning_commit~1..ending_commit` is the best syntax to use. Since I do `cherry-pick` very rarely, it's useful to have the extra explicitness of the `~1` so that when I search for it in my bash history I don't have to go searching the internet again to figure out exactly what the `^` means.

Answer (score 144):

The simplest way to do this is with the `onto` option to `rebase`. Suppose that the branch which current finishes at `a` is called mybranch and this is the branch that you want to move `c`-`f` onto.

```
# checkout mybranch
git checkout mybranch

# reset it to f (currently includes a)
git reset --hard f

# rebase every commit after b and transplant it onto a
git rebase --onto a b
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you also add `git checkout secondbranch && git rebase mybranch` for full answer

Comment: This answer helped me a lot to get my head around which commit is which in this scenario. And: you can use `rebase`'s interactive mode, too. Thanks, @Charles!

Comment: The beauty of this approach is that you can use `--interactive` to remove some commits from the sequence or reorder them prior to the "cherry pick". +1

Comment: Wild that you have to give the commit that you _don't_ want to rebase as one of the argumente (`b` in this example) but yes this has worked for me.

Comment: This answer did the trick for me. I used the rebase commands in conjunction with `--committer-date-is-author-date` to keep the original commit timestamps (incompatible with `--interactive`)

Answer (score 100):

Or the requested one-liner:

```
git rebase --onto a b f
```

Comment: Upvoted but will leave you in detached HEAD state if f is a commit (as opposed to a branch) - you should edit to add that one should checkout a branch as in [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12646996/281545)

Comment: Why bother with the rest?

Comment: One should note that cherry-picking a bunch of commits is not equivalent to rebasing them. The original poster seems to want the effect of rebasing, if one looks at the diagrams, but rebasing is not safe if you have already published your commits to a team or public repo.

Comment: I like this one but once you're in detached HEAD then you should `git branch tmp` (to save your detached HEAD state) + `git checkout destination-branch` (checkout to your destination, maybe develop) + `git merge tmp` (merge your detached HEAD into your destination)

Answer (score 80):

You can use a serial combination of `git rebase` and `git branch` to apply a group of commits onto another branch. As already [posted by wolfc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6126712/356895) the first command actually copies the commits. However, the change is not visible until you add a branch name to the top most commit of the group.

*Please open the picture in a new tab ...*

[image: Workflow]

To summarize the commands in text form:

1. Open *gitk* as a independent process using the command: `gitk --all &`.
2. Run `git rebase --onto a b f`.
3. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> in *gitk*. Nothing changes. But no `HEAD` is marked.
4. Run `git branch selection`
5. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> in *gitk*. The new branch with its commits appears.

This should clarify things:

- Commit `a` is the new root destination of the group.
- Commit `b` is the commit before the first commit of the group (exclusive).
- Commit `f` is the last commit of the group (inclusive).

Afterwards, you could use `git checkout feature && git reset --hard b` to delete the commits `c` till `f` from the `feature` branch.

In addition to this answer, I wrote a [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20210115134249/http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120928/git-how-to-copy-a-range-of-commits-from-one-branch-to-another/) which describes the commands in another scenario which should help to generally use it.

Comment: If the mybranch (the a..f commits) is not needed anymore this can be simplified to: `git rebase --onto a b mybranch` and btw - which program does those nifty git pictures ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Thanks for your comment. I think I used http://cacoo.com to draw the pictures.

Answer (score 58):

To apply J. B. Rainsberger and sschaef's comments to specifically answer the question... To use a cherry-pick range on this example:

```
git checkout a
git cherry-pick b..f
```

or

```
git checkout a
git cherry-pick c^..f
```

Comment: I use `git 2.7.0.windows.1` and noticed that when I try to cherry pick range of commits everything is ok but git doesn't tell you anywhere that you have to do `git cherry-pick --continue | --abort | --quit` before you try to commit/cherry-pick again. So if you cherry-pick range of commits you gonna need to run `git cherry-pick --continue` every time you are ready(resolving conflicts or such) with a commit from the given range.

Comment: I did exactly same, but

    fatal: Cannot find 'a..b'

Comment: I don't know where I'm wrong but when I do 'git cherry-pick c^..f' on my side, this includes the commit f but not the commit c. But as I read everywhere, it's supposed to define c and f as inclusive. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Samuel yes, that's correct. The `^` after the c actually means "the commit before c" which is b in this case. This is why `c^..f` is synonymous to `b..f`. Try doing `git log c^..f` and you should see commits c through f, exactly the same as if you did `git log b..f`

Answer (score 36):

To cherry pick from a **commit id** up to the **tip of the branch**, you can use:

```bash
git cherry-pick commit_id^..branch_name
```

Comment: This is already part of answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31640427/96823

Comment: This answer is actually different and was helpful to me. It specifies the branch name, not the final commit SHA.

Comment: I got "fatal: bad revision" error

Comment: @Dentrax I get the same error, did you manage to find a reason for it?

Comment: Nvm, it turns out I was using a `-` instead of `...`

Answer (score 28):

```bash
git rev-list --reverse b..f | xargs -n 1 git cherry-pick
```

> `git rev-list` prints all revisions from branch `b` to `f` (reversed) so that when each line (the commit hash) is passed in order, it will cherry pick each one onto the current git `HEAD`. i.e. `git cherry-pick {hash of c}; git cherry-pick {hash of d}; ...`
>
> -- [@coderatchet comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits#comment67219205_1671606)

Comment: Works perfect if there is no conflicts, otherwise "rebase onto" might be easier as you will not have to figure out where it has stopped and re-applying the rest of the patches.

Comment: Please add comments explaining what this is doing

Comment: since no one explained... git rev-list prints all revisions from branch b to f (reversed) so that when each line (the commit hash) is passed in order, it will cherry pick each one onto the current git HEAD. i.e. `git cherry-pick {hash of c}; git cherry-pick {hash of d}; ...`

Comment: How is this different from `git cherry-pick b..f`? Maybe the `cherry-pick b..f` syntax didn't exist in 2009?

Comment: Without using xargs, as one final command, in case of merge conflicts (if your system has paste): `git cherry-pick -x $(git rev-list --reverse b..f | paste -sd ' ' -)`

Answer (score 19):

Another variant worth mentioning is that if you want the last `n` commits from a branch, the `~` syntax can be useful:

```
git cherry-pick some-branch~4..some-branch
```

In this case, the above command would pick the last 4 commits from a branch called `some-branch` (though you could also use a commit hash in place of a branch name)

Answer (score 10):

Cherry-pick multiple commits:

Checkout to your branch where you want to cherry-pick the commits

Use this command: (by partial hash)

```
git cherry-pick 1e038f10 1e038f11 1e038f12 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the simplest way to do it could be to:

1. record the merge-base between the two branches: `MERGE_BASE=$(git merge-base branch-a branch-b)`
2. fast-forward or rebase the older branch onto the newer branch
3. rebase the resulting branch onto itself, starting at the merge base from step 1, and manually remove commits that are not desired:

   ```
   git rebase ${SAVED_MERGE_BASE} -i
   ```

   Alternatively, if there are only a few new commits, skip step 1, and simply use

   ```
   git rebase HEAD^^^^^^^ -i
   ```

   in the first step, using enough `^` to move past the merge-base.

You will see something like this in the interactive rebase:

```
pick 3139276 commit a
pick c1b421d commit b
pick 7204ee5 commit c
pick 6ae9419 commit d
pick 0152077 commit e
pick 2656623 commit f
```

Then remove lines b (and any others you want)

Answer (score 2):

---

I need cherry pick a commit from one branch to another on priority, but commits here were difficult to understand, hope below helps with a easy one:

---

Procedure to do below:

1. Get 1 commit with name ( "Remove Last Name field") , from "dev" branch
2. Commit it in "hotfix1" branch

---

1 . Get commit details from "dev" branch

```
// Go to "dev" branch
git checkout dev

// Get the commit id (1e2e3e4e1 here)
git log --oneline

    > ...
    > ...
    > 1e2e3e4e1     Remove Last Name field
    > ...
    > ...
```

2 . Push the commit to "hotfix1" branch

```
// Go to "hotfix1" branch
git checkout hotfix1

// Get the commit (1e2e3e4e1) from "dev" branch to "hotfix1" branch
git cherry-pick 1e2e3e4e1

// verify changes are correct
gitk

// push to "hotfix1" branch
git push
```

---

To do multiple at once, only 1 change in the above, give all commit ids in sequence:

```
git cherry-pick 1e2e3e4e1 1e2e3e4e2 1e2e3e4e3
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that will allow you to cherry-pick multiple commits in a row simply by telling the script which source and target branches for the cherry picks and the number of commits:

https://gist.github.com/nickboldt/99ac1dc4eb4c9ff003a1effef2eb2d81

To cherry-pick from your branch to master (uses the current branch as source):

```
./gcpl.sh -m
```

To cherry-pick the latest 5 commits from your 6.19.x branch to master:

```
./gcpl.sh -c 5 -s 6.19.x -t master
```

Comment: Why would this script be needed when you can do that with Git directly?...

Comment: Less typing, and my script automatically picks the commits for you, so you don't have to cherry pick each one by its SHA. Anyway, YMMV.

Comment: Never use a script if you don't understand what the script does, and why it does it. Otherwise you will never learn git.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively using **GitHub Desktop Application**,

You can **multi-select** commits in the history tab of the source branch, then right-click to get the option "Cherry-Pick Selected Commits".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to commit-ish, [you can pipe in a list of SHAs from stdin](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt-codegitrev-list--reversemaster--READMEgitcherry-pick-n--stdincode).

```sh
git rev-list --reverse ..main -- path/ | git cherry-pick --stdin
```

`rev-list` is basically the *plumbing* command (the "ugly" but fast cousin) of `git-log`
**NB** that **`--reverse`** is needed.

You can do more advanced stuff this way rather than simply a commit range.

Answer (score -1):

Not really an answer on HOW to cherry pick multiple commits but a way to avoid too much merging. I did this using IntelliJ but it should be easy to do on the command line as well.

You can make a temporary branch from the last commit just before the first one you want to cherry pick from. Then cherry pick everything you need into this temporary branch. This should generally be easy without many conflicts.

Then squash all the cherry picked commits. This will turn all the back and forth changes into single changes.

Now merge that single commit into your actual target branch. You will not have to resolve conflicts more than once.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to this question. While interesting in some ways, it's not really an answer to the question asked, unfortunately.

Answer (score -4):

```
git format-patch --full-index --binary --stdout range... | git am -3
```

Comment: Please add comments explaining what this is doing