# Create a branch in Git from another branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-workflow, git-flow

I have two branches: **master** and **dev**

I want to create a "feature branch" from the *dev* branch.

Currently on the branch *dev*, I do:

```
git checkout -b myfeature dev
```

... (some work)

```
git commit -am "blablabla"
git push origin myfeature
```

But, after visualizing my branches, I got:

```
--**master**
------0-----0-----0-----0-----0
------------------------**dev**----**myfeature**
```

I mean that the branch seems [fast-forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673869/what-is-git-fast-forwarding) merged, and I don't understand why...

What am I doing wrong?

How can you branch off from another branch and push back to the remote repository for the feature branch?

All that in a branching model like [the one described here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: To be clear, are you asking why the myfeature branch is ff merged, as opposed to some other form of merge? Or are you asking why it was merged at all? The latter question would make more sense to me, as I see no merge command preceding the apparent ff merge observation.

Comment: in your case myfeature is just few commits ahead of dev, that's why it is visualized that way. They don't have and point where commits diverge. Once dev branch gets some additional commit, you'll see it as branches with diverged commits that can't be just fast-forwarded.

Answer (score 2312, accepted):

If you like the method in the link you've posted, have a look at [Git Flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow).

It's a set of scripts he created for that workflow.

But to answer your question:

```
git checkout -b myFeature dev
```

Creates the *MyFeature* branch off *dev*. Do your work and then

```
git commit -am "Your message"
```

Now merge your changes to *dev* without a fast-forward

```
git checkout dev
git merge --no-ff myFeature
```

Now push the changes to the server

```
git push origin dev
git push origin myFeature
```

And you'll see it how you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;)
I did the same (without merging yet)
After looking at Git Flow source code it's roughly the same...
I don't get why when I create my feature branch, commit and push to it (remote), the branch seems merged when I visualize all my branches

Comment: Because you are pushing the myFeature branch to the server, and it shows that it has come off the dev branch. There are no merges. My example merges to the dev branch and pushes that merged branch to the server.

Comment: what is the importance of pushing `myFeature` after it has been merged wit `dev`?

Comment: @spartacus If `myFeature` branch was pushed to the server before merging, then nothing. But if `myFeature` isn't yet pushed to the server and you want it to appear in the server, you must push it appart.

Comment: is `git checkout -b myFeature dev` the same as these 3 commands: `git checkout dev`, then `git branch myFeature`, and then `git checkout myFeature`?

Comment: It is, or it should be. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: The way I read your sequence is: **1)** branch off, do your work and commit **2)** switch back to dev and merge it with feature **3)** push dev **4)** push feature **My question:** Why do push *both* `dev` & `feature`? shouldn't you just push after step 3 and be done? Don't you have all the new feature code you needed merged?

Comment: How would you do this with an already existing 'feature' branch? Like in the OP's question?

Comment: @Honey once you have checked out dev and merged the feature branch into it, just pushing dev would be enough - I agree

Comment: What if i want to push myFeature on the remote server before i finish work on this feature? May i skip merge with dev? (Feature do not exists on remote server yet)

Comment: Is there a way to define `dev` as the default branch from where I want to create the others from, removing the need of the last param in `git checkout -b newBranch dev`, making it `git checkout -b newBranch`?

Comment: To clarify for other newbies, [this is what a `--no-ff` merge looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMD5h.png)

Comment: This only works for me if I branch off of `origin/dev`, not off of `dev`.

Comment: I am glad I found @A__'s comment, this helped a lot to visualize why to use the no fast-forward, I feel like this should be added to the answer!
If you use the merge with fast-forward there is no clear way to tell where your feature starts and ends as it brings all the commits from the new feature branch into the development branch with no reference points!

Comment: whats the diffrence between  git checkout -b myFeature dev &  git checkout -b myFeature origin/dev. What to do if local dev branch is not updated?

Comment: why `git commit -am` instead of `git commit -m` ?

Comment: @Cin88 https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+commit+-am

Comment: `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'myFeature' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'dev' which can not be resolved as commit?`

Answer (score 704):

If you want create a new branch from any of the existing branches in Git, just follow the options.

First change/checkout into the branch from where you want to create a new branch. For example, if you have the following branches like:

- **master**
- **dev**
- **branch1**

So if you want to create a new branch called ***"subbranch_of_b1"*** under the branch named ***"branch1"*** follow the steps:

1. Checkout or change into **"branch1"**

   ```
    git checkout branch1
   ```
2. Now create your new branch called **"subbranch_of_b1"** under the **"branch1"** using the following command.

   ```
    git checkout -b subbranch_of_b1 branch1
   ```

   The above will create a new branch called **subbranch_of_b1** under the branch **branch1** (note that `branch1` in the above command isn't mandatory since the HEAD is currently pointing to it, you can precise it if you are on a different branch though).
3. Now after working with the **subbranch_of_b1** you can commit and push or merge it locally or remotely.

[image: A sample Graphical Illustration Of Creating Branches Under another Branch]

Push the *subbranch_of_b1* to remote:

```
 git push origin subbranch_of_b1
```

Comment: how to push the subbranch_of_b1 to remote ??

Comment: @user269867 : " git push origin subbranch_of_b1 " will do this job for you.

Comment: Now , If i push changes to master , will it occur in branch1 automatically ?

Comment: *note that branch1 in the above command isn't mandatory since the HEAD is currently pointing to it, you can precise it if you are on a different branch though* that's what I was looking for

Comment: I came here wondering if `git checkout -b some-branch` is shorthand for `git checkout -b some-branch master`.  It turns out that `git checkout -b some-branch` is shorthand for `git checkout -b some-branch <current_active_branch>`

Comment: `git push origin subbranch_of_b1` is exactly what OP said they already did. This answer is incomplete as it doesn't address how to push without ff merging.

Comment: @Frank.  The default of "<current_active_branch>" has gotten me into trouble sometimes, thus my personal preference is to spell-out the source branch !  Aka, my assumptions on my part were bad sometimes.

Comment: thanks. only it is a little confusing to call the new branch `subbranch_of_b1`, it is just a new branch created from base branch, `branch1` in this case. It is in equal level as other branches in the repo. There isn't a thing as sub-branch in git, just not the logic.

Comment: @MasterYoda To merge the master ("dev" in the example) branch to branch1 you should `git checkout dev` `git pull` `git checkout branch1` `git merge dev`

Answer (score 97):

### Various ways to create a branch in Git from another branch:

This answer adds some additional insight, not already present in the existing answers, regarding just the *title* of the question itself (**Create a branch in Git from another branch**), but does *not* address the more narrow specifics of the question which already have sufficient answers here.

I'm adding this because I really needed to know how to do #1 below just now (create a new branch from a branch I do *not* have checked out), and it wasn't obvious how to do it, and Google searches led to here as a top search result. So, I'll share my findings here. This isn't touched upon well, if at all, by any other answer here.

While I'm at it, I'll also add my other most-common `git branch` commands I use in my regular workflow, below.

### 1. To create a new branch from a branch you do ***not*** have checked out:

Create `branch2` from `branch1` while you have any branch whatsoever checked out (ex: let's say you have `master` checked out):

```bash
git branch branch2 branch1
```

The general format is:

```bash
git branch <new_branch> [from_branch]
```

`man git branch` shows it as follows. What I call `<new_branch>` is what they call `<branchname>`, and what I call `[from_branch]` is what they call `[<start-point>]`:

> ```
> git branch [--track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
> ```

### 2. To create a new branch from the branch you ***do*** have checked out:

```bash
git branch new_branch
```

This is great for making backups before rebasing, squashing, hard resetting, etc.—before doing anything which could mess up your branch badly.

Example: I'm on `feature_branch1`, and I'm about to squash 20 commits into 1 using `git rebase -i master`. In case I ever want to "undo" this, let's back up this branch first! I do this **ALL...THE...TIME** and find it super helpful and comforting to know I can always *easily* go back to this backup branch and re-branch off of it to try again in case I mess up `feature_branch1` in the process:

```bash
git branch feature_branch1_BAK_20200814-1320hrs_about_to_squash
```

The `20200814-1320hrs` part is the date and time in format `YYYYMMDD-HHMMhrs`, so that would be 13:20 hours (1:20 pm) on 14 Aug. 2020. This way I have an easy way to find my backup branches until I'm sure I'm ready to delete them. If you don't do this and you mess up badly, you have to use `git reflog` to go find your branch prior to messing it up, which is much harder, more stressful, and more error-prone.

### Interjection: notes about `git checkout` vs `git switch`

1. The classic, universal "Swiss army knife" which can do 1000 things: `git checkout`.
2. The new and experimental alternative commands to `git checkout`: `git switch` + `git restore`.

*`git switch` was added recently in Git v2.23. See your git version with `git --version`. It is designed to be an extremely limited form of `git checkout`, designed *only* to switch branches rather than also having the ability to check out or restore files, like `git checkout` can do. Read more here: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/commands/git-switch.*

See also: [What does git checkout still do after git switch got introduced?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66629531/4561887). `git restore` offers some of the rest of the functionality of `git checkout` which `git switch` does not contain.

Both `man git switch` and `man git restore` caution:

> THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE.

So, feel free to stick with `git checkout` if you like. Its behavior is not likely to change.

I pretty much just use `git checkout` myself, but you are welcome to use `git switch` (and `git restore` to restore or "check out" files) if you like.

### 3. To create *and check out* a new branch from the branch you ***do*** have checked out:

```bash
# the standard, "classic" command most people still use; `-b` stands
# for "create 'b'ranch"
git checkout -b new_branch

# the newer, "experimental" command now available as of Git v2.23; `-c` stands
# for "'c'reate branch"
git switch -c new_branch
```

To make it obvious what is happening there, know that this one command above is equivalent to these *two* separate commands:

```bash
# classic
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch

# OR: new/experimental as of Git v2.23
git branch new_branch
git switch new_branch
```

### 4. To create *and check out* a new branch from a branch you do *not* have checked out:

```bash
# classic
git checkout -b new_branch from_branch

# OR: new/experimental as of Git v2.23
git switch -c new_branch from_branch
```

To make it obvious what is happening there, know that this one command above is equivalent to these *three* separate commands:

```bash
# classic
git checkout from_branch
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch

# OR: new/experimental as of Git v2.23
git switch from_branch
git branch new_branch
git switch new_branch
```

### 5. To rename a branch

Just like renaming a regular file or folder in the terminal, `git` considered "renaming" to be more like a 'm'ove command, so you use `git branch -m` to rename a branch. Here's the general format:

```bash
git branch -m <old_name> <new_name>
```

`man git branch` shows it like this:

> ```
> git branch (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>
> ```

Example: let's rename `branch_1` to `branch_1.5`:

```bash
git branch -m branch_1 branch_1.5
```

OR, if you already have `branch_1` checked out, you can rename the *currently-checked-out branch* to `branch_1.5` like this:

```bash
git branch -m branch_1.5
```

### 6. To create a new feature branch (`feature2`) based off of the latest upstream changes on `main` when you currently have `feature1` checked out

Let's put a lot of what we learned above together to present a very common example we need to run whenever we finish one feature and need to start another one.

```bash
# The beginner/intermediate way

git checkout main           # check out main branch
git pull                    # pull latest upstream changes down
git checkout -b feature2    # create branch `feature2` from `main`, and check
                                # it out, all in one step`

# The advanced way

# [this is what I do--I'll explain why, below]
git fetch origin main:main      # pull latest upstream changes down from the
                                    # remote `main` branch, to the
                                    # locally-stored remote-tracking **hidden**
                                    # branch named `origin/main`, **and** to
                                    # the local `main` branch
git checkout -b feature2 main   # create branch `feature2` from `main`, and
                                    # check it out, all in one step`

# OR (nearly the same thing)
git fetch origin main           # pull latest upstream changes down from the
                                    # remote `main` branch, to the
                                    # locally-stored remote-tracking **hidden**
                                    # branch named `origin/main`. This does NOT
                                    # update the local `main` branch though!
git checkout -b feature2 origin/main # create branch `feature2` from
                                        # `origin/main`, and check it out, all
                                        # in one step`
```

So, when I'm on branch `feature1`, and have just finished it and am ready to start on a new `feature2` based off of the latest `main` branch, why do I do this:

```bash
git fetch origin main:main
git checkout -b feature2 main
```

...instead of this?:

```bash
git checkout main
git pull
git checkout -b feature2
```

The answer, surprisingly, is that `git checkout` can be a **horribly slow and heavy operation!**—taking up to **3+ hours** on a massive mono-repo utilizing [`git lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) post-checkout hooks in the repo's `.git/hooks/post-checkout` file. Let me explain. The `.git/hooks/post-checkout` file is an executable file containing a script that git will run after each time you run `git checkout`. If it contains a call to `git lfs post-checkout "$@"`, then it may try to download **20+ GB** of `git lfs` data (specific to the repo I work in—your scenario may vary) after running an innocent-looking `git checkout`. I don't want to do that! So, I skip the `git checkout` process to avoid that hassle and get started on my `feature2` branch immediately *without* downloading all of that stuff I don't need first!

### See also:

1. Quick links to **my answers I reference frequently and consider to be "git fundamentals":**

   1. [Various ways to create a branch in git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63418267/4561887)
   2. [All about checking out files or directories in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258783/4561887)
   3. [Who is "us" and who is "them" according to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63911630/4561887)
   4. [How to use `git diff` filters via `--diff-filter=`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66649684/4561887)
   5. [All about searching (via `grep` or similar) in your git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77917015/4561887)
   6. [How to use `git lfs` as a basic user: What is the difference between `git lfs fetch`, `git lfs fetch --all`, and `git lfs pull`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610495/4561887)

Comment: Best answer. Other answers are confusing since they tend to focus on branching and switching to the created branch at the same time using `git checkout`.

Answer (score 76):

**Create a Branch**

- Create branch when master branch is checked out. Here commits in master will be synced to the branch you created.

  `git branch branch1`
- Create branch when branch1 is checked out . Here commits in branch1 will be synced to  branch2
  `git branch branch2`

---

**Checkout a Branch**

git checkout command switch branches or restore working tree files

- `git checkout branchname`

---

**Renaming a Branch**

- `git branch -m branch1 newbranchname`

---

**Delete a Branch**

- `git branch -d branch-to-delete`
- `git branch -D branch-to-delete`
  ( *force deletion without checking the merged status* )

---

**Create and Switch Branch**

- `git checkout -b branchname`

---

**Branches that are completely included**

- `git branch --merged`

---

---

### Branch Differences [ git diff branch1..branch2 ]

**Multiline difference**

- `git diff master..branch1`

**Singleline difference**

- `git diff --color-words branch1..branch2`

Comment: Also after renaming the branch use `git push origin :old-name new-name` to delete the old-name remote branch and push the new-name local branch.

Answer (score 38):

To create a branch from another branch in your local directory you can use the following command.

```
git checkout -b <sub-branch> branch
```

#### For example:

- the name of the new branch to be created is 'XYZ'
- the name of the branch, 'ABC', under which 'XYZ' has to be created

```
git checkout -b XYZ ABC
```

Answer (score 19):

Git 2.23 introduces [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) and [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) to split the responsibilities of `git checkout`.

**Creating a new branch from an existing branch as of Git 2.23:**

`git switch -c my-new-branch`

*Switched to a new branch 'my-new-branch'*

- **-c** is short for **--create** and replaces the well-known *git checkout -b*

*Take a look at [this](https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/) GitHub blog post explaining the changes in greater detail:*

> Git 2.23 brings a new pair of experimental commands to the suite of existing
> ones: **git switch** and **git restore**. These two are meant to eventually
> provide a better interface for the well-known git checkout. The new
> commands intend to each have a clear separation, neatly divvying up
> what the many responsibilities of *git checkout*

Answer (score 13):

Do simultaneous work on the `dev` branch. In your scenario, the feature branch moves forward from the tip of the *dev* branch, but the *dev* branch does not change. It's easier to draw as a straight line, because it can be thought of as forward motion. You made it to point A on *dev*, and from there you simply continued on a parallel path. The two branches have not really diverged.

Now, if you make a commit on *dev*, before merging, you will again begin at the same commit, A, but now features will go to C and *dev* to B. This will show the split you are trying to visualize, as the branches have now diverged.

```
*-----*Dev-------*Feature
```

Versus

```
       /----*DevB
*-----*DevA
       \----*FeatureC
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to make a branch from some another branch then follow the below steps:

**Assumptions**:

1. You are currently in the *master* branch.
2. You have no changes to commit. (If you have any changes to commit, stash it!)
3. `BranchExisting` is the name of branch from which you need to make a new branch with name `BranchMyNew`.

**Steps**:

1. Fetch the branch to your local machine.

   ```
   git fetch origin BranchExisting : BranchExisting
   ```

This command will create a new branch in your local with same branch name.

2. Now, from the *master* branch checkout to the newly fetched branch

   ```
   git checkout BranchExisting
   ```
3. You are now in BranchExisting. Now create a new branch from this existing branch.

   ```
   git checkout -b BranchMyNew
   ```

Here you go!

Answer (score 6):

This is going to create new branch from current branch:

```
git checkout -b your_new_branch_name
```

If you want to create new_branch of an existing branch then:

```
git checkout -b your_new_branch_name existing_branch_name
```

Answer (score 1):

For creating a branch from another one can use this syntax as well:

```
git push origin refs/heads/<sourceBranch>:refs/heads/<targetBranch>
```

It is a little shorter than "git checkout -b " + "git push origin "

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the *develop* branch:

```
git checkout develop
```

Creates *feature/foo* branch of *develop*.

```
git checkout -b feature/foo develop
```

Merge the changes to develop without a fast-forward

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff myFeature
```

Now push changes to the server:

```
git push origin develop
git push origin feature/foo
```

Comment: not sure why this comment is needed when it's pretty word-to-word with the accepted answer and has less context in the comments too.

Comment: This was more helpful for me than original answer. I have been regular user of git in past but since last 2 year, i was using some other source control. i just wanted to have quick refresher instead of going through large answer

Comment: [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch/4470822#4470822).

Answer (score 1):

***It's worked for me:***

Go to your [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) repository, and select the branch name from where you want to create a new branch, as shown in the below image:

[image: Image 2]

Then type the branch name you want to create, and click on *Create branch*.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: The question asked about Git, not Github. Not everyone uses Github.