# How can I push a local Git branch to a remote with a different name easily?

Tags: git, version-control, git-push, git-remote

I've been wondering if there's an easy way to push and pull a local branch with a remote branch with a different name without always specifying both names.

For example:

```
$ git clone myrepo.git
$ git checkout -b newb
$ ...
$ git commit -m "Some change"
$ git push origin newb:remote_branch_name
```

Now if someone updates remote_branch_name, I can:

```
$ git pull
```

And everything is merged / fast-forwarded. However, if I make changes in my local "newb", I can't:

```
$ git push
```

Instead, I have to:

```
% git push origin newb:remote_branch_name
```

Seems a little silly. If `git-pull` uses `git-config branch.newb.merge` to determine where to pull from, why couldn't `git-push` have a similar config option? Is there a nice shortcut for this or should I just continue the long way?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Sure. Just set your `push.default` to `upstream` to push branches to their upstreams (which is the same that `pull` will pull from, defined by `branch.newb.merge`), rather than pushing branches to ones matching in name (which is the default setting for `push.default`, `matching`).

```
git config push.default upstream
```

Note that this used to be called `tracking` not `upstream` before Git 1.7.4.2, so if you're using an older version of Git, use `tracking` instead. The `push.default` option was added in Git 1.6.4, so if you're on an older version than that, you won't have this option at all and will need to explicitly specify the branch to push to.

Comment: That was it! This applies to all branches that are tracking, but that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested to know whether there is a shorthand for the branch name I've checked out. I might just want to `git push buildserver .:test_this` where the `.` shall be the local branch name which I don't necessarily know. I could look it up, sure, but if there was a short hand, like the dot, for that, it'd be cool.

Comment: @FrederickNord `HEAD` is the shorthand you're looking for. `HEAD` is what points to the currently checked out branch, or directly to a particular commit if you have a detached head.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the `Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote` error for me. My local repo was up to date, but the names were just different.

Comment: This affects how `push`  behaves for **all** branches in **all** your repos.  You can limit it to just one repo with `--local`, but for a single branch, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76589598/5353461).

Answer (score 296):

When you do the initial push add [the -u parameter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push--u):

```
git push -u origin my_branch:remote_branch
```

Subsequent pushes will go where you want.

EDIT:

As per the comment, that only sets up pull.

```
git branch --set-upstream
```

should do it.

Comment: `-u` just sets the upstream, which according to the question, is already set. He needs to set `push.default` to `upstrem` in order to get `push` to respect the upstream setting, since by default only `pull` does.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - at least not on never versions of git

Comment: git branch --set-upstream only does the pull setup "pushRemote" needs to be set after this.

Comment: I don't think `git branch --set-upstream` is necessary. Note: my `git --version` is 2.17.1.

Comment: The syntax you show above is important in, and referenced by, my answer here: [How to change the owner of a PR on GitHub / How to commandeer an open GitHub PR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66539232/4561887). How did you learn that `from_branch:to_branch` syntax by the way? Is it buried in the `man git push` pages somewhere?

Comment: Found it: it's actually near the top of `man git push` under the "`<refspec>...`" section: "The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`." And then later: "`:<dst>` part can be omitted—such a push will update a ref that `<src>` normally updates without any `<refspec>` on the command line." This is very non-intuitive and not obvious at all without an example.

Comment: I had way too many questions about this stuff so I did a ton of research and experimenting and added my own, new answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70302053/4561887

Comment: @wheredidthatnamecomefrom, I don't think that's correct.

Comment: Don't know where my mind was at the time that and can't delete the comment either. The setup is per branch other than that  `git push -u origin my_branch:remote_branch` should be enough.

Comment: thats why i keep scrolling for other solutions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 29):

The command by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1864976/adam-dymitruk) is now deprecated. You can use:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/my_remote_branch my_local_branch
```

to set the upstream branch of `my_local_branch` to `origin/my_remote_branch`.

Comment: Can you provide a link supporting the information you share about -u being deprecated? Docs for latest version regarding push at [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) seem to suggest it's current. 

Thanks in advance - it could be very helpful to readers to follow up for more info.

Comment: Agree with @KayV, especially that I got this message when trying to create a new remote branch with a name different to my local branch: 'If you are planning to push out a new local branch that will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.'

Comment: This only works for `fetch`, `merge`, and `pull`. For per-branch `push` config, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76589598/5353461).

Answer (score 27):

> How can I push a local Git branch to a remote with a different name easily?

### Summary:

Here is a short summary of just the key commands you need in general:

```bash
# push from your local `branch2` to a remote `branch1` (push to a branch with
# a different name) on the remote named `origin`
git push -u origin branch2:branch1
# pull from a remote branch `branch1` into your currently-checked-out branch
# (which could have a different name--ex: `branch2`)
git pull origin branch1

# Set your upstream to something new in case you want to change it; ex: set your
# currently-checked-out branch (perhaps `branch2`) to track `branch1` on the 
# remote named `origin`
git branch -u origin/branch1
# Unset your upstream
git branch --unset-upstream

# See what your upstream is currently set to
git branch -vv
```

---

### Details:

The following sections are covered below, in this order:

1. Pushing to another branch
2. Pulling from another branch
3. Setting and unsetting an upstream branch to track

There are too many incomplete and partial answers here which leave me with a lot of questions and a lot to be desired. So, after a bunch of effort and research and experimenting, here is my attempt at providing a complete solution.

### 1. Pushing from your local branch to a remote branch with a different name

To **push FROM your local `branch2` TO remote `branch1`**, you must specify both branches like this:

```bash
# Push from local `branch2` to remote `branch1`
git push origin branch2:branch1

# General form: push from local `from_branch` to remote `to_branch`. 
# - Watch out!: see also the additional explanations and NB note below!
git push <remote> <from_branch>[:to_branch]
```

Notice, however, that the square brackets I have written in the general form above indicate the `:to_branch` part is *optional*. What I mean is that to push from a local branch with one name to a remote branch with a different name, that part is NOT optional, but, as a general git command, the command will run if you do not include the `:to_branch` part, meaning it is optional in that sense. But, it may produce unexpected results! Take a look at this command, for example:

```bash
# (push to a remote branch with the **same name** as the local branch)

# Reduced **and confusing** form: this pushes from local `branch2` (even if you
# don't currently have it checked-out!) to remote `branch2`.
git checkout branch3 
git push origin branch2          # Push from local branch2 to remote branch2
```

You might have local `branch3` currently checked-out, and think that `git push origin branch2` will push your local `branch3` to the remote `branch2`, since you have `branch3` currently checked-out on your system, but this is NOT what will happen! Rather, `git push origin branch2` will push your local `branch2` to your remote `branch2`, again, *even if you do NOT have `branch2` currently checked-out!* `git push origin branch2` is therefore an equivalent short-hand of this:

```bash
# These 2 commands are **exactly identical**! The 1st cmd is the short form
# of the 2nd. 
git push origin branch2          # Push from local branch2 to remote branch2
git push origin branch2:branch2  # Push from local branch2 to remote branch2
```

The short form of the cmd just above produces very confusing behavior if you think it will push from your currently-checked-out branch instead. Here is a [Nota bene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene) note summarizing the behavior described above:

*NB: In the general form `git push <remote> <from_branch>[:to_branch]`, if you don't specify the remote TO branch with `:to_branch`, it is assumed to be the same name as your local FROM branch, `from_branch`, on the `remote`! This means if you type only `git push origin branch2` instead of `git push origin some_other_branch:branch2`, it pushes FROM your local `branch2` TO the remote copy of `branch2`, EVEN IF YOU DIDNT HAVE `branch2` locally checked-out at the time of running the command! This can be VERY CONFUSING if you *thought* typing `git push origin branch2` had just told your currently-checked out branch, `some_other_branch`, to push to `branch2` on the remote and instead, the local `branch2` got pushed to the remote `branch2`.*

The documentation for the general form (`git push <remote> <from_branch>[:to_branch]`) is hard to find, but it's actually found in the `man git push` pages near the top under the `"<refspec>...`" section:

> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.

And then later:

> `:<dst>` part can be omitted—such a push will update a ref that `<src>` normally updates without any `<refspec>` on the command line.

I think this documentation is non-intuitive and very difficult to understand, however, without some examples and my explanation above.

**[BETTER FORM OF `git push`]** You can also **set the upstream branch at the same time as pushing**:

```bash
# Push from local `branch2` to the remote `branch1`, while also at the same time
# setting `branch2` to track `origin/branch1` as the upstream
git push -u origin branch2:branch1
# OR (same thing)
git push --set-upstream origin branch2:branch1
# General form
git push -u <remote> <from_branch>[:to_branch]
```

As part of the output of the command above, you should see:

> ```
> Branch 'branch2' set up to track remote branch 'branch1' from 'origin'.
> ```

To make it obvious what is happening there, know that either of the two commands just above are equivalent to these *two* separate commands:

```bash
git push origin branch2:branch1
git branch -u origin/branch1
```

Now, to **view what your branch's upstream branch is currently set to**, run the *double-verbose* (`-vv`) `git branch` cmd:

```bash
git branch -vv
```

Sample output:
Here you can see that the upstream branch is `origin/master`, which means the `master` branch on the remote named `origin`:

> ```
> * master b2f0466 [origin/master] c/array_filter_and_remove_element.c: add O(n) in-place solution
> ```

Notes:

1. `-vv` above means "double verbose". This means it will print `git branch` not just verbosely, but double verbosely, or extra verbosely. The "extra verbose" content now printed includes the upstream branch in square brackets, as shown above: `[origin/matser]`.
2. You can view all your remotes with `git remote -v`. `origin` is the remote shown in the examples above.

### 2. Pulling from a remote branch with a different name to your local branch

**[Recommended if you already have branch `branch2` checked-out locally!]** To **pull FROM `branch1` on the remote named `origin`, TO `branch2`**, you must specify the remote branch to pull from, like this:

```bash
# THIS ASSUMES YOU ARE ALREADY CHECKED-OUT ON BRANCH `branch2`!

git pull origin branch1
# General form
git pull <remote> [from_branch]
```

You can also specify both branches, but *I'm not entirely sure what the difference is in this case*:

```bash
git pull origin branch1:branch2

# The general form seems to be:
git pull <remote> <from_branch>[:to_branch]
```

**The following command only works *if the remote and local branches have the same name!* (therefore it does NOT answer this Stack Overflow question). This command is recommended if you do NOT already have branch `some_branch` checked-out!**

```bash
# Pull FROM a remote branch named `some_branch` TO a local branch named
# `some_branch`, while you do NOT have `some_branch` locally checked-out.
git fetch origin some_branch:some_branch
# General form
git fetch <remote> <from_branch>:<to_branch>

# The above is a special form of `git fetch`, and (I believe) requires that 
# `from_branch` and `to_branch` are **the same branch name**. It is roughly 
# equivalent to the following *several* commands:
git checkout any_other_branch
# this `git fetch` cmd updates the **locally-stored**, hidden, remote-tracking
# branch named `origin/some_branch` with the latest changes from the branch
# by this name stored on the remote server named `origin`
git fetch origin some_branch 
git checkout some_branch
git merge origin/some_branch  # merge `origin/some_branch` into `some_branch`
git checkout any_other_branch # go back to the branch we started on
```

Notes:

1. Unlike `git push`, `git pull` does NOT have a `-u` option.
2. See also another of my answers: [How to change the owner of a PR on GitHub / How to commandeer an open GitHub PR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539231/how-to-change-the-owner-of-a-pr-on-github-how-to-commandeer-an-open-github-pr/66539232#66539232)
3. The `git fetch origin some_branch:some_branch` command is done with the same `some_branch` name used twice--in both locations in the command. The difference is simply that `git fetch origin some_branch` only updates the **locally-stored**, hidden, remote-tracking branch named `origin/some_branch` with the latest changes from the branch by this name stored on the remote server named `origin`, whereas `git fetch origin some_branch:some_branch` does that PLUS also updates the locally-stored visible `some_branch` with those changes too.

   1. If you feel confused about this, you need to learn that *for every 1 `some_branch`* you *think* you have, you actually have up to *3 branches*: 1) a local branch `some_branch`, 2) a remote branch `some_branch` on a remote server named `origin`, and 3) and locally-stored, hidden, remote-tracking branch named `origin/some_branch`. Read here for more info. and for where I first learned this concept of **3 branches** per branch: [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely/23961231#23961231). See also [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely/23961231#comment107954274_23961231), under that answer.

### 3. Configuring your local branch to track or untrack a remote branch

You can **set your local branch** named `branch2` **to track an upstream branch** named `branch1` **at the same time as pushing** by using the `git push -u` cmd shown above.

You can also **set your local branch named `branch2` to track an upstream branch named `branch1`** like this:

```bash
# Set branch2 to track origin/branch1 (`branch1` on remote `origin`)
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch1 branch2
# OR (same thing as just above)
git branch -u origin/branch1 branch2
# General form
git branch -u <remote>/<to_branch> [from_branch]

# OR, same as above if the currently-checked-out branch is `branch2`
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch1
# OR (same thing as just above)
git branch -u origin/branch1
# General form
git branch -u <remote>/<to_branch>
```

To **UNset your upstream branch for `branch2`**, so it no longer tracks the previously-set upstream branch (which was `origin/branch1` in the examples above), run this:

```bash
git branch --unset-upstream branch2
# OR, same as above if the currently-checked-out branch is `branch2`
git branch --unset-upstream
```

And again, as already shown above, to **view what your branch's upstream branch is currently set to**, run the *double-verbose* (`-vv`) `git branch` cmd:

```bash
git branch -vv
```

### References:

1. Where I first learned the `git push -u origin local_FROM_branch:remote_TO_branch` syntax: [@Adam Dymitruk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740047/4561887)
2. https://devconnected.com/how-to-set-upstream-branch-on-git/
3. [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely/23961231#23961231)

### Related `git` topics I've written about:

1. BEGINNER:

   1. [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch/63418267#63418267)
2. INTERMEDIATE:

   1. [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits/69472178#69472178)
3. ADVANCED:

   1. [How to get just one file from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch/65258783#65258783)
   2. [Who is "us" and who is "them" according to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025314/who-is-us-and-who-is-them-according-to-git/63911630#63911630)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really detailed but a little hard to follow in short time: (e.g.  EVEN IF YOU DIDNT HAVE `from_branch` locally checked-out at
#   the time of running the command! This can be VERY CONFUSING if
#   you *thought* you had just told your currently-checked out branch to push
#   to some branch on the remote and instead, the **local copy of that some
#   branch** (which you do NOT currently have checked-out) gets pushed to the
#   remote.)  This part can be a little more concise?

Comment: @LanSi, this is a very confusing topic for sure, and difficult for me to explain. I updated my answer a bunch in an attempt to clarify it and make that part easier to understand. Let me know if it's easier to follow now.

Answer (score 6):

**How to push to a branch of a different name on Git**

You will usually push your local branch to a remote branch of the same name—but not always.

To push to a branch of a different name, you just need to specify the `branch you want to push` and the name of the branch you want to push to separated by a colon (:).

For example, if you want to push a branch called `some-branch` to `my-feature`:

```
(some-branch)$ git push origin some-branch:my-feature
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To github.com:johnmosesman/burner-repo.git
 + 728f0df...8bf04ea some-branch -> my-feature
```

**How to push all local branches to the remote**

You won't need to push all branches from your local very often, but if you do you can add the `--all` flag:

```
(main)$ git branch
* main
  my-feature

(main)$ git push --all
...
To github.com:johnmosesman/burner-repo.git
   b7f661f..6e36148  main -> main
 * [new branch]      my-feature -> my-feature
```

Comment: This seems like the best up-to-date answer

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a config option to make `git` push to upstream branches by default.

Use the following set of statements so you don't have to do `git push origin local:remote` every time:

```
# Set remote branch with a different name as an upstream branch 
# for local branch currently checked out
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/remote_branch_name

# Change the default behavior for git-push (see manpage for git-config)
git config push.default upstream

# Now git will push to the upstream branch by default
git push
```

After setting the current branch's upstream to a remote branch with a different name, you need to change the default behavior of `git push` to `upstream` (see manpage for `git-config`).
Now, `git push` will obey these rules and push to the set upstream.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it's the only one that addresses both 1) that the local branch needs to be set to tracking the remote branch; and 2) the default behaviour of `push` has to be set as well. 
Also, it explains the solution in as few words as needed.

Answer (score 2):

## Push and create a temporary remote branch

If you want to:

- Push the current branch to remote under a new name, but:
- Don't change the remote tracking branch of current branch, and:
- Don't create a local branch under the new name,

Then it's as simple as this:

```
git push origin HEAD:temp-branch-name
```

*Note: You can replace `HEAD` with any other branch or commit ID to push that instead.*

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. `push` **all** the repo's branches to where they get pulled from via [`push.default = upstream`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-pushdefault)
2. Change a single branch with [`remote.<name>.push`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtpush)

---

To have **all** your repo's branches push to the branch that they pull from, use:

```
git config --local push.default upstream
```

Note: this will affect other branches, also.

---

To setup a single branch's remote push pair (Example: local `main` to `origin/master`):

1. Set the branch's remote

   ```
    git branch --set-upstream-to origin
   ```
2. Set the remote's push mapping

   ```
   git config --local remote.origin.push main:master
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the process that has worked for me.

```
git clone original-repo-url
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin new-repo-url
```

Now your new repo will be ‘origin’ and the original repo is ‘upstream’. Confirm it by running git remote -v. (Side note: Upstream is used to fetch from the original repo - in order to keep your local copy in sync with the project you want to contribute to - and origin is used to pull and push since you can contribute to your own repo).

`git push origin master`

Now your new remote repo's master (on Github) will be in-sync with the original master, but it won't have any of the feature branches.

```
git rebase upstream/branch-name
git push origin master
```

Rebase is a smart merge. Then push to master again and you’ll see the selected feature branch as master on the new repo.

Optional:

```
git remote rm upstream
git remote add upstream new-repo-url
```

Answer (score 0):

One cool thing you can do if you have a bunch of files in your local branch that you want to save to a different branch, is to do a `git stash` to save all your modified files (this is repository wide), then you do a `git checkout remoteBranchYouWant` then do a `git stash pop` and now all your modified files are ready in your newly checked-out branch and you can commit and push these up to the new branch as you wish.