# How to use a different branch name when pushing to remote repo

Tags: git, github

Say I added a new remote repo under my project folder by:

```
git remote add origin2 ADDRESS_OF_NEW_REMOTE_REPO
```

then, I start to push my code to my new remote repo. Locally, my branch name is "`develop`", I want to push to my new remote repo with a different branch name, say "`production`", can I simply do this by command:

```
git push origin2 production
```

though locally, I am under branch "`develop`" ? What is the correct way to do this? and what potential problems could be caused by doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I push a local Git branch to a remote with a different name easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738797/how-can-i-push-a-local-git-branch-to-a-remote-with-a-different-name-easily)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ git push yourremotename local_branch:remote_branch
```

(`yourremotename` here is remote name, often "origin", "github", "heroku" or similar)

So for you something like:

```
$ git push origin2 develop:production
```

---

For the most cases I think I would just rename the local branch to avoid confusion, if it's possible.

```
$ git branch -m develop production
```

This way it is easier to keep track as to what branch references which.

I understand though that for example Heroku would only deploy from master branch, so sometimes you do want to have the names separate.