# Commit changes to a pull request

Tags: git, github

On Github, I wanted to make a change to a pull request.

```
1. git fetch origin
2. git checkout -b show-buttons origin/my-branch
```

Then I made some changes to files.

Now I want to add these files back to the pull request, and finish merging it with master and pushing it. What are the right next steps?

Here is what I was thinking:

```
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "Fixed some bugs on mypullrequest."
5. git merge master
6. git push origin master
```

Comment: You don't need to merge master into your branch - this would typically be done once your pull request has been reviewed and accepted.  Make your changes locally, then push back upstream without the merge.

Comment: Interesting was just following github's instructions at the bottom of their pull request page "Use the command line to resolve conflicts before continuing".

Comment: Do you know the syntax for pushing back upstream? tried `git push origin/mypullrequestbranch mypullrequest branch` but got `fatal: 'origin/mypullrequestbranch' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: Ahh, apologies, in that case sounds like you have merge conflicts.

Comment: `git push` alone will push your current branch back up to origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to push any local branch to a remote branch where a pull request is in progress:

```
git push origin localBranch:remoteBranch
```

It is best to establish localBranch as tracking remoteBranch

```
git push origin -u localBranch:remoteBranch
# in your case, possibly:
git push origin -u show-buttons origin/my-branch
```

See more at "[How can I push a local Git branch to a remote with a different name easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740047/6309)".

If your master is up-to-date (compared to the master of the original upstream repo), then rebasing your local branch on top of it can be a good idea

```
git checkout show-buttons 
git rebase master
```

But then you will have to force the push:

```
git push -f origin -u show-buttons origin/my-branch
```