# git - push certain branch to remote's certain branch

Tags: git, heroku

Following Heroku's deployment tutorial, I need to push my code to the `heroku` remote's `master`. I am currently on `feature_branch`, and need to deploy the code on this branch.

`git push heroku feature_branch master` is not working

How do I push `feature_branch` to `master` on of my remote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I push a local Git branch to a remote with a different name easily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738797/how-can-i-push-a-local-git-branch-to-a-remote-with-a-different-name-easily)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git push origin local-name:remote-name`

Normally when we do a push in git we do something like git push origin master, which really means push from the local branch named master to the remote branch named master. If you want to push to a remote branch with a different name than your local branch, separate the local and remote names with a colon: