# How to push changes as a branch to remote server not in Main line

Tags: git

I have pulled a project from git repository(remote server). I did some modification.

Now I need to push as branch in a server not in main line.
For example, In server, V1->V2->V3.
My working area is on V2. And I want to push as V2.1. Not as V4.

Usual command i used for Pushing is `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master/issue5221`.
Is there some thing to replace `master` in that command to push as a branch?

I tried some thing like this `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/my_branch/issue5221`. But it is not working. Since "`my_branch`" is not in remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to push HEAD to a new branch (created on receiving the commit) with:

```
git push origin HEAD:my_branch/issue5221
```

(more generally, [you can push a local branch to a remote repo on a different branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740047/6309))

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Gerrit. So you need ask the administrator to create the branch `refs/heads/my_branch/issue5221`, after which you can push to `refs/for/my_branch/issue5221`. If this is not an official branch, you can push it to a sandbox branch via `git push origin HEAD:refs/sandbox/<your-username>/<any-name-you-want>`. `refs/sandbox/<your-username>/*` cannot be fetched via `git clone`, but can be done via `git fetch origin refs/sandbox/<your-username>/* && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`. And other users are not allowed to update this ref.