# How to push by default to a differently named branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-remote

I have two branches:

```
master
demo_master
```

And two remotes:

```
origin
demo_origin
```

How can I configure git to automatically push **master to origin/master** and **demo_master to demo_origin/master** when issuing `git push` command?

---

I've tried to achieve the desired result by

```
git push --set-upstream demo_origin demo_master:master
```

However, git spits out the following error whenever I try to use `git push`:

> fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the
>   name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch on the
>   remote, use
>
> ```
> git push demo_origin HEAD:master
> ```
>
> To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use
>
> ```
> git push demo_origin demo_master
> ```

Comment: `git config push.default upstream`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I push a local Git branch to a remote with a different name easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738797/how-can-i-push-a-local-git-branch-to-a-remote-with-a-different-name-easily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [set the `push.default` configuration](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_variables) properly:

> Defines the action `git push` should take if no refspec is explicitly given. Different values are well-suited for specific workflows; for instance, in a purely central workflow (i.e. the fetch source is equal to the push destination), `upstream` is probably what you want.

With Git 2.0, this setting was set to `simple` by default, to make it easy for beginners:

> `simple` - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different from the local one.
>
> When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners.

As the option says, Git will refuse to push to a branch that has a different name. In order to achieve that, you need to set it to `upstream`:

> `upstream` - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called `@{upstream}`). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).

So, do `git config -g push.default upstream`, and then it should work just fine with `git push --set-upstream demo_origin master:demo_master`. (note that the local branch comes first in `local:remote`)

Answer (score 1):

> > With Git 2.0, this setting was set to simple by default, to make it easy for beginners:
> >
> > **`simple`** - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different from the local one.
> >
> > When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners.

That has been rewritten with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), adding clarification around `git push`.

See [commit 90cfb26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90cfb2666b5913e0be4ffb84630866287dde4f9a), [commit 7e6d72b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e6d72bb111b080ef37e26fbdfe080672521c570), [commit b8e8b98](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8e8b98647f02e721fc3c1b5db6936ba7c1c1167), [commit 6b010c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b010c80a2596c75d562afa5ab098ffff21bab06), [commit d099b9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d099b9c9c723e8ca974e5ece027165e2824a1b89), [commit 3b9fd83](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b9fd8361f1ed98f06df24d406b9a618c7f39df1), [commit 050f76b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/050f76b9af75bf69110d542e0cee569d0112f320) (31 May 2021) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 07e230d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/07e230d762bde9ce5fa41384efb8caed4c7de684), 13 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90cfb2666b5913e0be4ffb84630866287dde4f9a): push: explain `default=simple` correctly
>
> <sup>Cc: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>

> The simple mode only barfs when working on a centralized workflow, and there's no configured upstream branch with the same name.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/90cfb2666b5913e0be4ffb84630866287dde4f9a/Documentation/config/push.txt#L27-L34):

> ### `simple`
>
> Pushes the current branch with the same name on the remote.
>
> If you are working on a centralized workflow (pushing to the same repository you pull from, which is typically `origin`), then you need to configure an upstream branch with the same name.
>
> This mode is the default since Git 2.0, and is the safest option suited for
> beginners.

---

That explains why the default setting is not the right one for your case, and you need, as noted above:

```
git config -g push.default upstream, 
git push --set-upstream demo_origin master:demo_master
```

Note the second push is to be done only for the first push: once the upstream branch is set, a simple `git push` (no parameters) will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

On `master` local branch use `git push origin -u master` and on the `demo_master` branch use `git push demo_origin -u master`

Another solution would be using `git branch -u origin/master` from `master` branch and `git branch -u demo_origin/master` from `demo_master` branch.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches

Comment: I want to push demo_master to demo_origin **master**. Aren't these commands equivalent to what I was doing?

Comment: I think that the right way to achieve it using `set-upstream-to` is `git branch --set-upstream-to demo_origin/master` when you are on the `demo_master` branch.