# Setting upstream branch to remote with different name than your local

Tags: git, github

I created a new branch off an existing PR on github using the browse branches dropdown...typed in an new branch name so it would create a new one based off the PR I was looking at.

I then went locally and did a `git checkout -b myBranch`

How do I sync up my branch with the remote?  I did not name my local branch as the same name as the remote.

`git push -u origin my_branch` - I assume that's if you already have things synced AND that the local and remote branch names are exactly the same.

So what about my situation?

I tried this but got an error

▶ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/WA-3  WA-3
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/feature/WA-3' does not exist

**More info to help**

The remote branch's name is `feature/WA-3` while my local  is named `W3`

▶ git remote show origin

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/xxxx.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/xxxx.git
  HEAD branch: develop
  Remote branches:
    develop                         tracked
    feature/WA-3                    new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
    master                          tracked
    refs/remotes/origin/w9-homepage stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
    w1-log-in              tracked
    wa-9                  tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    develop            merges with remote develop
    w1-log-in merges with remote w1-user-can-log-in
    w9-homepage        merges with remote wa-9-homepage
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop            pushes to develop            (up to date)
    w1-log-in pushes to w1-log-in (up to date)
```

[image]

Comment: `new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)` sounds weird. Have you tried to fetch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I push a local Git branch to a remote with a different name easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738797/how-can-i-push-a-local-git-branch-to-a-remote-with-a-different-name-easily)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the colon notation:

```
git push -u origin local_branch:remote_branch
```

Comment: ▶ git branch -u feature/WA-3:WA-3
error: the requested upstream branch 'feature/WA-3:WA-3' does not exist

Comment: is that a bad name I gave it in github?  why can't it find it?

Comment: I literally named the remote branch as `feature/WA-3`

Comment: how weird, I see the branch on github yet when I do this it's not listing that particular branch:" `▶ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  origin/develop
  origin/master
  origin/w1-log-in
  origin/w9
  origin/wa-9-homepage`

Comment: I really can't believe this.  I deleted the remote and re-created a new branch off that PR called simply `W3` and same deal it doesn't even see it when I do a `git branch -r`

Comment: ok yours works ▶ git push -u origin WA-3:WA-3         
Branch WA-3 set up to track remote branch WA-3 from origin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I am missing something here, I always fall back to being a beginner when it comes to this.

You can just easily rename your branch, for example using lazygit that makes it a one button step, or just check out a new branch from your given one with the right name.

Trying at first just with `push`:

```bash
$ git push
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:master

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD

To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.
```

You see here two options, choose the latter.

Thus, at first, rename your branch to the name that it has to have in the repository. As soon as your local branch name is the one that you want to see in the repository, you only need to run

```
git push -f origin HEAD
```

so that the new local branch (HEAD) would be pushed on top of the remote master (origin). It pushes to the remote.

Looks like:

```bash
$ git push -f origin HEAD
Enumerating objects: 21, done.
Counting objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 1019 bytes | 1019.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote:
remote: To create a merge request for my_new_remote_branch_name_that_is_now_the_name_of_HEAD, visit:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/my_URL_to_the_repo
remote:
To gitlab.com:my_URL_to_the_repo
 * [new branch]        HEAD -> my_new_remote_branch_name_that_is_now_the_name_of_HEAD
```

The command `git origin HEAD` is just short for
`git push -u origin HEAD:my_new_remote_branch_name_that_is_now_the_name_of_HEAD`
Which is the same as:
`git push --set-upstream origin HEAD:my_new_remote_branch_name_that_is_now_the_name_of_HEAD`

Only if you want to choose a remote name that is not the one of HEAD, you need the long command of the answer.