# git branch from branch instead of from master

Tags: git

I have created a adjacent branch from another adjacent branch instead of from master branch. I have added the changes and pushed. Now I have seen that it is like

```
*   master commit update readme (this is how I have noticed it)
| * adj_br_2 commit blahblah
| * adj_br_1 commit blah
|/
*   master commit blblbl
```

Now I want to create the 2nd branch from master instead of from 1st branch.

```
*   master commit update readme (this is how I have noticed it)
| * adj_br_2 commit blahblah
|/
| * adj_br_1 commit blah
|/
*   master commit blblbl
```

Is there a way to do it without clearing and recreating the branch? In fact I need a fast way to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could rebase your changes with `master` as your base instead of the other branch.  Sometimes that process will require some serious manual merge conflict resolution though.

Comment: Can you please post the syntax, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git create a branch from another branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/git-create-a-branch-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just create a new one from the master:

```
git checkout -b new-branch master
```

and then if your original branch contained commits you want to take in the new branch, you can cherry-pick them:

```
git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 ...
```

and then you can remove the second adjacent branch you wanted to recreate:

```
git branch -d adj_br_2
```

In git, creating branches is pretty cheap and fast, you can afford to create new ones whenever you need to.

Comment: If I do the delete part it says that `error: The branch 'adj_br_2' is not fully merged.` How to fix this?

Comment: it's because it contains commits (commit hashes) which are only in it. if you are sure you will lose nothing if you delete it (eg. you cherry-picked all the commits you needed), you can force the delete with: git branch -D branch-name (capital D)