# GIT: How to include commited and pushed changes from one branch to a brand new branch?

Tags: git

I have a branch(created from master)(branch_a) with several commits and pushes. Now is there a way to include all these changes into a brand new branch(from Master)(branch_b) that I am about to create?

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b branch_a
Now in branch_a i do some work(x,y,z)
git add .
git commit -m 
git push
```

And now,

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b branch_b
Now in branch_b
```

How can I include my work(x,y,z) into the branch_b and then commit and push it ?

Thanks

Comment: Just create the new branch?

Comment: And how to include all my changes from the other branch ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git create a branch from another branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/git-create-a-branch-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 1):

If you need just x, y, z commits  from branch_a (on top of master) then create a new branch from that branch. It will be same as branch_a.

If branch_a contains some other work that you don't want then you have few posibilities.

- create new branch from master and cherry-pick commits from branch_a
- create new branch from branch_a and do interactive rebase on top of (historically) first commit that you need and eject later commits that you dont need
  (this will rewrite your history - sha1 hashes)

Ask for details if you have problems with executing this tasks  or refer to other answers about cherry-pick and interactive rebase.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to just create `branch_b` at `branch_a`:

```
$ git checkout -b branch_b branch_a
```

This is short-hand for the two commands

```
$ git checkout branch_a
$ git checkout -b branch_b
```

I find the first useful since it is less typing.

Note that `master` is not special. It is just a branch name. This means that anywhere you see `master` in any documentation or example, you replace it with any other branch.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I include my work(x,y,z) into the branch_b and then commit and push it ?

If all you need is get all changes from `branch_a` and put them on `branch_b`. You could create the second brach FROM branch_a.

Like:

```
git checkout -b branch_b branch_a
```

This will create a brand new `branc_b` from `branch_a` and automatically switch to branch_b. Just commit and push later.