# Create new branch based on current branch to work on a new feature

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

How do I create a new branch in `git` to begin work on a new feature?

I want the new branch to be a duplicate of the current branch (ie, the new branch's HEAD should be the same as the current HEAD).

---

Question differentiation:

- [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4470523/5353461) seems related but is actually about why a branch is fast-forward merged.
- [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch) is about creating a new branch on a [remote](https://manned.org/git-remote).

Comment: Reopen queue reviewers: you may wish to read the meta.so discussion of this question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373487/5353461).

Comment: (Nitpick) I think you're having the wrong links for the "question differentiation" section. There are 4 links but only 2 questions.

Comment: @user202729 The bottom two links were initially marked as duplicates as mentioned in the meta discussion linked in my previous comment. I'll edit the differentiation to make that more obvious.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

To create and start work on a new branch called `FEATURE`, you do:

```
git checkout -b FEATURE
```

**Detailed explanation**

To create a branch called `FEATURE`:

```
git branch FEATURE
```

However, this does not change your current branch.

You can then `checkout` the newly created branch (which means make to it the branch you're currently working on:

```
git checkout FEATURE
```

(You can see the current branch marked with a `*` in the output of `git branch --list`.)

Generally you want to start working in the branch you have just created, so the shortcut equivalent for both commands is `git checkout -b FEATURE`, which creates a new branch, then does `checkout` on it.

Answer (score 39):

If you say

```
$ git checkout -b myFeatureBranch anotherBranch
```

It'll create `myFeatureBranch` off of `anotherBranch`.  But if you say

```
$ git checkout -b myFeatureBranch
```

It'll create `myFeatureBranch` off of the current branch.

Comment: and how do we push this new branch to the remote repository

Comment: In my opinion, this answer was clearer than the accepted one - kudos to @doctorram

Comment: @mustafa In case somebody needs a quick reference if you have a remote called origin "git push -u origin myFeatureBranch".