# How to keep working on a branched branch with --no-ff?

Tags: git, command-line, git-branch

I made a branch `feature` from another branch `dev` and merged it with `--no-ff` using [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4470822/1757149) to end up with a tree like the diagram below (but instead of "master" its `dev`):

[image]

Now I've done more work on `feature` and want to push it to the `feature` branch (like the next yellow point in the `feature` sequence in the above diagram). Do I continue on this branched branch with

```
$ git push origin feature
```

or must I do

```
$ git checkout dev
$ git merge --no-ff feature
```

each time I want to push to `feature`? I want to keep `feature` separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to merge back `dev` to `feature` each time you add more commits.
You can just add those commits and push your `feature` branch.

You should still merge `feature` to `dev` locally if you want to check everything is still working there.

Answer (score -1):

- `get checkout dev`
- `git merge --no-ff feature`
- `git add <resolved-files>`
- `git commit`