# How to create a development branch from master branch in git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash

In my repository, I have a master branch which has all of the latest code.

I need to have a development branch which is cut from the master branch, so that developers can further cut feature/bugfix branches from the development branch and merge code back to the development branch.

How can I create a development branch from the master branch such that work can be done on both in parallel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-branch%5D+how+to+create+branch

Answer (score 6):

First, checkout your **master** branch:

`git checkout master`

Then cut a branch called **develop**:

`git checkout -b develop`

When you need to make further changes to **develop**, cut new branches in a similar fashion while **develop** is checked out:

`git checkout -b feature`

To merge a **feature** back into your **develop** branch, checkout **develop** and execute a merge:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff feature
```

(While `--no-ff` is not necessary, I prefer using this to ensure an explicit merge commit is shown in history.)

I would *highly* recommend investigating a Git workflow. A very common one is [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), but there are others.