# Github subbranch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Im currently working on a project for school where I need to use git & github. I'm fairly new to git but know the basic commands for committing, branching and pushing.

Now my question is, how can I create the following branch structure :

`master 
   |
   ---- branch_1 
          |
           ---- subbranch_1
           ---- subbranch 2`

I've already tried a couple of things : first I followed a guide which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch) but all my branches where on the same hierarchical order. I also exactly followed[this](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) article but here again my branches were on the same level.

Please can anyone help me with this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Branch is just a pointer to a commit. There's no hierarchy of branches.

Comment: `git checkout master && git checkout -b branch_1 && git checkout -b subbranch_1 && git checkout branch_1 && git checkout -b subbranch_2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As castis says in the comment.

First `git checkout master`. This puts you on the `master` branch.

Next, create `branch_1` with `git checkout -b branch_1`, this also switches you to `branch_1`.

From there you can create `subbranch_1` with `git checkout -b subbranch_1`. But now you are on `subbranch_1`...

So, you need to go back to `branch_1`, by running `git checkout branch_1` this puts you on `branch_1`.

From there you can create `subbranch_2` with `git checkout -b subbranch_2`.

You will now be on `subbranch_2`.

Comment: Okay, this is what I achieved so far https://github.com/JensVanhulst/test/network. Is this right or not ? Because the arrows of subbranch_1 and 2 are starting from master and not from branch_1 ?

Comment: Yes, because it is pointing at the commits, try committing on change into each branch and see what happens.