# Clone Branch and create a new from the first one

Tags: git, git-branch

I cloned a branch `"feature/first"` 
Now I want to create a new one `"feature/second"` from `"feature/first"` and work with different things

my steps:
1. `git clone [...] -b feature/first`
2. ?

how can I do that?

Comment: I smell a confusion between cloning and branching *(third today if I'm not mistaken ^^)*

Comment: You can simply `checkout` the `"feature/first"` branch and then create the new branch with `git checkout -b "feature/second"`, have you tried that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do the following actions:

- `git checkout feature/first` to ensure to be on the "feature/first" branch;
- `git checkout -b "feature/second"` to create a new branch named "feature/second" and switch on it.

Note: *Pay attention on command*... you **clone** a repository and then you can switch or create branch with `git checkout` command.