# Is it possible to create GitHub branch like master:master-1?

Tags: git, github

This is something crazy but I need some clarification.

I want to create two branches like a master with different alias.

Example :

branch one: `master:master-1`

branch two: `master:master-2`

I tried from terminal `git checkout -b master:master-1`

Getting fatal error `fatal: master:master-1 is not a valid branch name.`

Any idea to create branches like above.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:` is not a valid character in a branch name.

Check the documentation for `git-check-ref-format`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format

Answer (score 2):

You're close the proper syntax. This will create and checkout master-1 at master's HEAD

```
git checkout -b master-1 master
```