# How to create a new branch under feature branch using Git commands?

Tags: git

For example, I have a branch named `/feature` and I wanted to create a new feature branch under it, like `feature/MyTask-01`.

I tried using command `git branch feature/MyTask-01` but it always gives me this error:

```
$ git branch feature/My-Task-01
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/feature/My-Task-01`: 'refs/heads/feature' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/feature/My-Task-01'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git stores branches in `refs/heads/`.

1. Creating a branch branch `feature` stores a file: `refs/heads/feature`.
2. Creating a branch `feature/abc` attempts to store a file `refs/heads/feature/abc`.

Both cannot be possible, since `refs/heads/feature` would need to be a file and a folder at the same time.

To resolve this, either

- delete the feature branch and stick to using `feature/x`, or
- call your second branch something which doesn't attempt to create the `feature/` folder, such as `feature_x`.

Comment: Note that *sometimes*, Git stores branches in a flat-file, `.git/packed-refs`. When Git is doing that, this restriction on names would not be necessary. Git enforces it anyway, so that when Git stores the branches in separate files, things don't suddenly stop working.

Comment: @grg Sorry for late reply, yeah this is what I am looking for. The /feature is a folder (submodule) when I saw it in the sourcetree. Thanks a lot man.