# GIT: Turn an existing branch into a sub-branch

Tags: git

Because my dev branch is a sub-branch of master, they don't share the same commitline:

[image: My dev is always a few commits ahead of my master]

Here's how I created dev as a sub-branch of master:

```
git checkout -b dev master
```

After some minor fixes, my master ended up a few commits ahead of my dev branch. I should have been on my dev branch first, but I didn't realize I was on master until I had already pushed the changes.

To fix that, I did a "git pull" to bring my dev up to speed with master. So far, so good.

**My Problem**

Now when I push commits to my dev branch, it no longer appears as a sub-branch of master. As you can see, their commitline has now merged:

[image]

How do I make dev a sub-branch again?

Comment: what does it mean `sub-branch`? Your definition `don't share the same commitline` has no practical meaning. Looks like you misunderstood how git works. Or at least I have no idea what is your problem (if you have one).

Comment: @ Marek R I created the dev branch this way "git checkout -b dev master". As you can see, dev was created from master. Essentially, I followed the this workflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch

Comment: When you created the dev branch it was based on the commit that master pointed to at this very moment. You could have created based on a tag (pointing at the same commit)  or the commit pointed at from master  with the same result. It is not possible to make it based on master "forever". You can rebase it however at any time back on master.

Comment: The fact that 'dev' was branched from 'master' does not make it in anyway subordinate.  There is no such thing as a "sub-branch".

Comment: Do you want the commit with log message "added devMode parameter" to still be in the master branch?  Or are you trying to re-write the history of master to remove it?

Comment: By merging the branches, **in this scenario** it looks like they would have the same history after the merge. Thus it doesn't show as separate branches in the graph visual. I'd bet if you make 2 different commits (1 for each branch) on master and dev, you will see the graph visual diverge again. I don't think you actually have the problem that you think you have though.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend using a tool like this one (which I swear by for newcomers). https://gmaster.io/
The branch visualization tool will give you a much better understanding of the history than the built in terminal git log --graph