# How can I branch from another branch, then delete origin branch?

Tags: git

I have two main branches: `master` and `develop`.

My usual workflow on a new feature is:

1. Create a new branch from develop: `git checkout -b <myfeature> develop`
2. Code and test the feature
3. Commit the changes: `git commit -a -m "<message>"`
4. Change back to develop: `git checkout develop`
5. Merge the feature back into develop: `git merge --no-ff <myfeature>`
6. Delete the branch: `git branch -d <myfeature>`
7. Push develop to remote: `git push origin develop`

Now I need to work on a new feature that requires the current feature. My new workflow would be:

1. Create a new branch from develop: `git checkout -b <myfeature> develop`
2. Code and test the feature
3. Commit the changes: `git commit -a -m "<message>"`
4. QA is currently validating
5. Create a new branch from myfeature: `git checkout -b <newfeature> <myfeature>`
6. Start coding newfeature
7. QA is done validating, commit current code: `git commit -a -m "<message>"`
8. Change back to develop: `git checkout develop`
9. Merge the feature back into develop: `git merge --no-ff <myfeature>`
10. Delete the branch: `git branch -d <myfeature>`
11. Push develop to remote: `git push origin develop`
12. Change back to newfeature: `git checkout newfeature`
13. Finish coding newfeature
14. Commit the changes: `git commit -a -m "<message>"`
15. Change back to develop: `git checkout develop`
16. Merge the feature back into develop: `git merge --no-ff <newfeature>`
17. Delete the branch: `git branch -d <newfeature>`
18. Push develop to remote: `git push origin develop`

Is this a proper workflow? Is there any repercussions to deleting the branch in step 10 (i.e. does it orphan newfeature?)?

The original guidelines were from [Vincent Driessen's A successful Git branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). I also read [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch), but it doesn't really get into deleting the branch that spawned the new branch.

Comment: If you're not doing pull requests what's the point of your feature branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a proper workflow?

That depends on what you want to achieve. There are many possible workflows.

> Is there any repercussions to deleting the branch in step 10 (i.e. does it orphan newfeature?)?

Branches are just pointers to a commit, they do not depend on each other. Deleting a branch removing that entry point to the graph, but it does not remove the commits by itself. As long as you have a way to go back to that commit from another branch, the commits will never be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with that.

Just be sure to manage those states with a little caution. Lets say. You work on A and clone B. But you need to do some changes on A after business found something they want to have changed. If you push A and want those changes now in B, git merge might result in duplicate commits. Instead use git rebase.

I am working solely with trunk-based development. https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/