# create a new branch from dev [ gitlab]

Tags: gitlab

Can anyone please help me how to create a branch from develop using console on linux OS?

I tried

```
git checkout -b my-branch
```

but not sure on how to create it from dev branch.

Comment: `git checkout -b my-branch dev`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
git checkout -b new-branch-name dev-branch-name
```

Comment: this says: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: Do you have .git folder in the root of the directory. If not then try git init command.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

Comment: fatal: 'dev' is not a commit and a branch 'My-Branch' cannot be created from it when I use git checkout -b My-Branch dev

Comment: Here dev is a placeholder, you should put your develop branch here. If the name of your development branch is "develop" then command should be "git checkout -b my-branch develop"

Comment: I have dev as development branch

Comment: Is your dev branch a remote branch or local?
What are you getting after git branch command?

Comment: current branch, dev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219241/discussion-between-manash-kumar-and-vuejsdev).