# create new branch with all commits from main branch in Github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I was working on the main branch of a repository that has multiple commits. But now, I want to create a new branch to this repository where I can get all the commits and codes I have done and pushed to the main branch.
How do I create a new branch to get all the commits from the main branch to the new one?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? What makes you think the new branch won't have the commits from main branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch)

Comment: @GaëlJ I am unsure how I can get all the commits from the main branch to the new branch. It would be helpful if you could give instructions on how to do this.

Comment: A branch is just a pointer to a specific commit. Commits aren't moved around. All you have to do is `git branch newbranch main`. This will make `newbranch` point to where `main` currently points to.