# Git Cherry-Pick and Conflicts

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

There are two different git branches. In one the development is going in (Branch1).

In other branch some PoC work is going on (Branch2). Now, I want to cherry-pick the changes from Branch1 to Branch2, so that Branch2 is up to date.

Now, after cherry-picking 4 or 5 changes, I am getting some merge conflict and I am unable to proceed with further cherry-picks.

Do, I need to resolve all the conflicts before proceeding to next cherry -pick or Can I somehow postpone the conflict resolution till I cherry-pick all the changes (and resolve all conflicts together)?

Further, is it suggested to do cherry-pick or branch merge in this case?

Comment: One possible way to avoid these cherry-pick conflicts is by doing the cherry-picking in the order of oldest commit to latest commit, i.e. based on commit date.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Do, I need to resolve all the conflicts before proceeding to next
>   cherry -pick

Yes, at least with the standard git setup. You cannot cherry-pick while there are conflicts.

Furthermore, in general conflicts get harder to resolve the more you have, so it's generally better to resolve them one by one.

That said, you *can* cherry-pick multiple commits at once, which would do what you are asking for. See e.g. [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits) . This is useful if for example some commits undo earlier commits. Then you'd want to cherry-pick all in one go, so you don't have to resolve conflicts for changes that are undone by later commits.

> Further, is it suggested to do cherry-pick or branch merge in this
>   case?

Generally, if you want to keep a feature branch up to date with main development, you just merge master -> feature branch. The main advantage is that a later merge feature branch -> master will be much less painful.

Cherry-picking is only useful if you must exclude some changes in master from your feature branch. Still, this will be painful so I'd try to avoid it.

Comment: Do you know if the inability to do this with standard `git` is an intentional design choice (and, if so, do you know why?), or just some accidental clumsiness?

Comment: @LSpice: I do not know the design history of this feature, but I assume it was intentional. Git has a general convention of disallowing many things (such as a rebase) with an "unclean" workspace (i.e. with uncommitted changes). This generally simplifies the design of many commands, and avoids nasty special cases (such as how to handle conflicts).

Answer (score 81):

Before proceeding:

- Install a proper mergetool. On Linux, I strongly suggest you to use meld:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install meld
  ```
- Configure your mergetool:

  ```
  git config --global merge.tool meld
  ```

Then, iterate in the following way:

```
git cherry-pick ....
git mergetool
git cherry-pick --continue
```

Answer (score 17):

Also, to complete what @claudio said, when cherry-picking you can also use a [merging strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies).

So you could something like this `git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs commit` or `git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X ours commit`

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time. Thanks