# Cherry-picking the same file for the second time, GIT raises it as conflict

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-rest-api

I am using the Azure REST API for a cherry-pick operation. Initially, the cherry-pick is successful. However, when new changes are pushed to the same file, and I attempt to perform a cherry-pick operation for that file again, Git raises a conflict.

**Requirement:**  The cherry pick is done to take out some feature development commits and merge them into QA branch, We don't want to push everything to the QA branch.

Cherry Pick Azure API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/cherry-picks/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2

> Error:  'status': 'failed', 'detailedStatus': {'currentCommitId':
> 'fe6d96', 'conflict': True}

When attempting to perform the same operation using the Azure DevOps UI, the following error occurs:

> Error: Encountered conflicts when cherry-picking commit "fe6d96". This
> operation needs to be performed locally.

Comment: Try to resolve the conflicts in PR before cherry pick

Comment: We are cherry picking some commits from dev and As I can see we can only raise PR after cherry pick is successfully done on a branch and then the generated branch will get merge into the main branch. For example a topic branch is created for cherry pick operation, after the operation is successful , we can raise a PR between the topic branch and QA branch.

Comment: If you will try to push new changes to the same file then it will show you conflicts when you try to cherry pick. So you need to resolve the conflicts in Azure DevOps UI before doing cherry pick again

Comment: That is the issue Azure DevOps saying it resolve the issue locally, disrupting the flow.

Comment: You will be able to see the conflicts in your PR, resolve them before proceeding further or else it will not allow you to cherry pick. I believe you can only resolve the conflicts locally.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830464/git-cherry-pick-and-conflicts

Comment: Some (perhaps most) conflicts require manual intervention. Is there any reason you can't resolve them locally?

Comment: Actually we are implementing CI-CD for Informatica assets and we finalized that we will cherry only those feature which are actually ready to be deployed in QA and then the same feature will be deployed to PROD, if any of the feature do not pass the QA testing, that feature will no be deployed into PROD. And we are cherry picking same file lots of time as they will get change frequently.

Comment: What do you mean by "cherry pick" ? do you mean the action in Azure on a specific merge request ?

Comment: Cherry-pick, getting out specific commit from a branch and merging them to another branch. I am creating a feature branch and in this branch I have a specific commit. The feature will get merge into QA branch. But when I am using the same file second time for cherry pic, it is showing me as conflict. And this all process I am doing using Azure REST API, I have given the link in the description.