# Git: How to apply the same modifications to another branch?

Tags: git

I've a master branch. It's the on-production code.

Every 'hotfix' must start from this branch

I've a develop branch. It's the 'stable-next-release' code.

Every new feature must start from this branch and is merge ONLY with this branch.

Today I take a mistake: I branched-off from develop for an hotfix.

Now I really need to apply the same modification to master branch, but I cannot merge the new hotfix branch because this will release every new feature already in develop.

Is there a way to ... sorry for bad words ... get a diff from develop and hotfix and the apply this modifications to master?

Is this probably what is called 'creating a patch' ?

Comment: So you have a branch that contains the changes for the fix? `rebase` might help if you haven't pushed that branch.

Comment: i've master, untouched, develop untouched, hotfix branch started from develop, and it's already commited and pushed. I need a way to apply the modifications to master instead of to develop branch.

Comment: Can't you use cherry-pick ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3933416/2454790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you are dealing with only a **few commits**, then you can `cherrypick` your commits to the other branch

   ```
   git checkout  master_branch
   ```

   now, identify the commits that were added to the `development_branch` and using the SHA (commit Ids) of those new commits, just cherrypick the commits:

   ```
   git cherry-pick <SHA>
   ```
2. If you are dealing with **lot of commits**, and you are **fine with not retaining the original commit messages**, then you can follow the diff-patch approach:

   ```
    git diff master_branch..development_branch > patch
    git checkout  master_branch
    git apply --check fix_empty_poster.patch  // dry run your patch
    git am --signoff < patch
   ```

Comment: i choose this answer because the path method is perfect for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could `cherry-pick` the hotfix from its branch:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick hotfix
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers suggest, if it is only one (or a couple of) commits, then cherry-pick works fine. Otherwise you can do the following, *which will retain the original commit messages*:

```
git branch master_hotfix your_hotfix_branch
git rebase --onto master `git merge-base develop master_hotfix` master_hotfix
git checkout master
git merge master_hotfix
```

This makes a new "copy" of the hotfix branch based on develop and moves it over to start from the master branch instead where you then can merge it.