# how to move git commits to and from the stash?

Tags: git

I am working in a team with a branching strategy that sometimes rewrites the upstream commit history for some of the branches.

It would be incredibly useful to be able to move the last N commits from my history into the stash, then reset HEAD, then move those stashes back into my local history, whilst preserving the commit messages.

How can I move commits between my local branch and the stash? And is there a way to automate this for N commits? e.g. to create aliases that would be invoked something like `git stashHistory 5; git popHistory 5`. Assume my current working directory has no changes when doing this.

Comment: I think you can use git cherry pick instead
http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-cherry-pick-changes-with-git

Comment: that's effectively how I do it right now. That involves getting the list of commit id, then resetting head, then copying and pasting each id manually. I'd like to automate this because I can easily have 10 commits that I need to apply.

Comment: aah.. then you should check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits

Comment: yeah, but that doesn't work when the branch is deleted beneath you :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically you can't *move* commits at all, not in the sense that you mean.  Moreover, "the stash" is actually just a single reference-name (`refs/stash`).  The `git stash` script uses the reflog to hide multiple items under that single name.  When you run `git stash save` to make a new one, the script creates a *new* commit (different from every other commit so far) and makes the stash point to it.<sup>1</sup>  It would be possible to achieve your goal this way, I think, but this is the wrong way to try it.

Fortunately, that's not a problem anyway.  What you really want is just a plain old `git rebase`!  The `git rebase` command simply automates a series of `git cherry-pick` operations with a `git reset` somewhere along the way.

Here's how this works.  You have your work, on your branch `B`, which you start doing when your upstream team has `upstream/B` pointing to the commit-chain I mark `o` (for old) here:

```
..- * - o - o - o           <-- upstream/B
                  \
                    x - y   <-- B
```

Now your upstream team goes and "rewrites history" in `upstream/B`, replacing the three old `o`s with new `n`s (maybe 4 `n`s, even).  The old ones are still there though, especially in *your* repo since your `B` includes them:

```
        n - n - n - n       <-- upstream/B
      /
..- * - o - o - o           <-- upstream/B@{1}, in reflog
                  \
                    x - y   <-- B
```

What I believe you want to do is to copy `x` and `y` (or a longer chain of 5 in your example) to new, slightly-different commits `x'` and `y'`, resulting in this graph:

```
                        x' - y'   <-- B
                      /
        n - n - n - n       <-- upstream/B
      /
..- * - o - o - o           <-- upstream/B@{1}, in reflog
                  \
                    x - y   <-- [reflog only]
```

To do this, you simply need to tell `git rebase` to start with the commit right after `upstream/B@{1}` (that's `x`) when rebasing branch `B` onto the new `upstream/B`:

```
$ git rebase --onto upstream/B 'upstream/B@{1}' B
```

This is why I left the reflog label `upstream/B@{1}` in the graph drawings: after a `git fetch` updates `upstream/B` with one of these rewrites, it's the label that lets you find `x` easily.  Note that if `upstream/B` has been updated several times, the reflog number might have increased beyond `1`.  (I also put the `...@{1}` into single quotes above, to protect it from shells—there are a few—that like to eat braces.  Chances are yours doesn't and they're not needed.)

The latest versions of git (2.x, though 1.9 had it I think) have a new flag option to `git merge-base` called `--fork-point` that is meant to help automatically figure out where the `o`-to-`x` transition is, even if the reflog number is no longer just `1`.  So if you have a new enough git you can totally automate the whole thing.  If not, you can count manually (as you have been doing), or manually poke through the `upstream/B` reflog to make sure `@{1}` is the right suffix.  In all cases, what you need is to locate that `o`-to-`x` transition, since that's the argument you must pass to `git rebase`.

(You might not need the `--onto` argument, but it's safe to include.  Without `--onto` git chooses the "on-to" from the branch's so-called "upstream".  This is a terribly confusing term, especially since one of the `rebase` arguments is actually *called* `upstream` and it means something different!  The upstream *argument* is where we are using `upstream/B@{1}`; it identifies commits to *exclude* from the rebase cherry-pick copying process.)

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, it's at least *two* new commits—two for plain `git stash save`, three if you add `-a` or `-u`—and the one to which the `refs/stash` reference points is a merge commit. It's not what one would normally think of as a merge; the script simply uses—one might say "abuses"—the multiple-parent-commits aspect of a merge commit to be able to store these commits and use a single reference-name to find all of them later.

Comment: Great explanation! Maybe I would add, that `reflog param` is not a nuber, but commit ID.

Comment: @kraag22: the reflog number I'm talking about is the one inside the curly braces. You can, indeed, use the raw commit ID directly instead—but then you're not using the reflog: `git rebase --onto face0ff cafedad` uses no reflog entries at all. (You can look up the IDs in the reflog and cut-and-paste them, if you prefer this method.)