# How to `git cherry-pick` a series?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I want to cherry-pick a series of commits. This is because neither (1): --ff-only merge nor (2): rebasing off each other nor (3): rebasing both off a shared branch and retrying (1) work in my particular case because my branches are so widely diverged and different. The commits that I want to cherry-pick, however, are on a rarely touched part of the code-base so there is no merge collision risk here. How can I save time by not having to cherry-pick a whole bunch of commits one-by-one?

Comment: Are they in a consecutive range, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits

Comment: git cherry-pick can handle several consecutive commit id like git cherry-pick 5f621c9 f1za0c9 5251415 but you will have to resolve your conflict one by one if you have some.