# Cherry-pick a pull request into a branch?

Tags: git

I need to get the changes from a pull request which isn't yet merged into a branch.

I could cherry-pick each commit from the branch but there are quite a few of them. Is there a quicker way to get all the changes from a pull request?

In case it makes a difference Im using Github.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits

Comment: I read thru the other 'duplicate' thread, didn't find any reference to pull-request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the pull request is from a branch that is contained in your repository, as RedX noted, you can follow the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits) post.

On the other hand, if the pull request is from someone's fork of your repository, you'll first have to add their repository as a remote, pull in their branches, then cherry-pick as described in the post above.

Comment: For example, if we have multiple commits in a pull request and after merging the pull request, can we cherry-pick the same pull request in other branches?

Comment: you cherry-pick commits not pull requests.

Comment: I can see it is available in GitLab but not in Bitbucket which I am using. Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/cherry_pick_changes.html