# How to rebase commits from another repository with a different history?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, rebase

We have two Git repositories.

Repo 1. Commits: A, B, C. This repository was created from SVN history.

Repo 2. Commits: D, E, F. This repository was created without SVN history, just by using the working copy (as of commit C) which became the commit D. In another words, the file trees of the commits C und D are the same.

Now, we want to merge both repositories so we have the full history in one repository. Is there a way to "copy/rebase/something else" all the commits E..F onto C?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to add *Repo 2* as a [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) in *Repo 1* using its *physical path* on disk and then simply [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) commits `E` and `F` on top of `C`.

So, in *Repo 1* you would do:

```
git remote add repo2 C:\Path\To\Repo2
git fetch repo2
```

then, assuming `E` and `F` are the latest two commits in the `master` branch in *Repo 2* and `C` is the latest commit in `master` in *Repo 1*, like this:

```
      master
     /
A-B-C
      repo2/master
     /
D-E-F
```

you would do:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick repo2/master~2..repo2/master
```

which will apply the patches from commits `E` and `F` on top of `C`:

```
           master
          /
A-B-C-E'-F'
      repo2/master
     /
D-E-F
```

Note that here I'm cherry-picking a *range of commits*, which is supported [since Git 1.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933416/26396).

Comment: Adding a local remote using its path is cute - I didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 2):

Are these remote repositories? If both C and F are on the same local repository then you should be able to rebase the branch pointing to F onto the branch pointing to C. If not try this:

1. Locally in Repo1 run
   a. `git remote add repo2 <Repo 2 URL>`
   b. `git push repo2 branchPointingToC`
2. Then locally in Repo2 run
   a. `git fetch`
   b. `git checkout branchPointingToF`
   c. `git rebase -i remotes/origin/branchPointingToC`

(N.B. If instead you followed [Enrico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37674353/575530) but wanted to rebase you would use `git rebase -i repo2/master` in place of his `git cherry-pick`.)