# Recover git history from legacy version of project

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick, git-workflow

Long story short:

1. Project is getting migrated to new git repository server
2. Someone only copies project files and pushes whole project to new server as initial commit
3. Work continues starting at that new initial commit for quite some time
4. I managed to find an old local copy of legacy project (before the switch to new server) and want to insert the old git history into the current version of the project (before the start of the current history). There are a few extra unwanted commits on the old local project

The branches essentially look like this:

```
                 old_master
                /
A--B--C--D--E--F

                  origin/new_master
                 /
init--G--H--I--J
```

where commit: `new_master` -> `init` = `old_master` -> `D`

So the end result would be something like:

```
                       origin/new_master
                      /
A--B--C--D--G--H--I--J
```

[How to rebase commits from another repository with a different history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673813/how-to-rebase-commits-from-another-repository-with-a-different-history) has a similar dilemma history wise that is solved with cherry picking. In my situation there are a huge amount of commits with complex branching that might be difficult to cherry pick. Is there an efficient way to do this using `rebase` or `rebase --onto`?

Comment: In the answer you have linked to, it is shown that you can cherry-pick a range of commits. Will that not do the job for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an efficient way to do this using `rebase` or `rebase --onto`?

Not in the general case, where there might be branching-and-merging.  (If the history in the new repository is strictly linear, then you can do this with a simple `git rebase --onto`.  It's not exactly *efficient* but it's just machine time, so who cares how efficient it is?)

The general solution to this is a *graft*, via `git replace`.

Let's look at what happens if you `git fetch` both the original and the new repositories into a *third* (otherwise totally empty) repository, using the drawings above.  You end up with:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- old/master

D'--G--H--I--J   <-- new/master
```

(note that the third repository does not yet have its own `master`).  Rather than calling the first commit in the `new/master` chain `init`, I've called it `D'` because presumably it has the same *snapshot* as commit `D` in `old/master`, but it has a different *hash*.

*Nothing*—no power on Earth—can change *any* of these existing commits.  But what if we copy commit `G` to a new commit `G'` whose parent is `D`?  Then we get this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- old/master
          \
           G'

       D'--G--H--I--J   <-- new/master
```

At the moment, new commit `G'` is just hanging out in the repository, with no way for us to *find* it.  Let's add a *name* by which we can find `G'`.  For now, let's call it `graft`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- old/master
          \
           G'  <-- graft

       D'--G--H--I--J   <-- new/master
```

Now, what if we could somehow get Git, when it's walking backwards along the `J`-then-`I`-then-`H`-then-`G`-then-`D'` (and then stop) chain, to, at the very last moment it can, *switch* from `G` to its graft `G'`?  That is, we'll make a dotted-line connection of some sort:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- old/master
          \
           G'  <-- graft
           :
       D'--G--H--I--J   <-- new/master
```

and convince Git to run `git log` as *show `J` then `I` then `H` then `G'` then `D` then `C` then `B` then `A`*.

It will now *look like* history reads this way, even though it doesn't, really.<sup>1</sup>

This is precisely what `git replace` does.  It makes *replacement objects*.  In the case of a commit, the replacement can take the form of a *graft*, like `G'`.  Rather than using the magic name `graft`, Git uses an even-more-magic name, `refs/replace/hash`, where *hash* is the hash ID of actual commit `G`.  Some of the time, you don't need to know this, and some of the time, you do.

The problem with this kind of replacement-commit graft is that `git clone` doesn't *clone* replacements, by default.<sup>2</sup>  So your third repository is a little weird when cloning.  Sometimes that's exactly what you want, and if so, that's fine.  Sometimes it's not, and if so, consider using `git filter-branch` or similar to *convert* the graft to a *fourth* repository in which the graft is now permanent, because the commits are copied to *new* commits (with new and different hash IDs) in which the *real*—but rewritten—history uses the grafted history, rather than the original history.

---

<sup>1</sup>Philosophical question:  Or does it?  Does history read the way history *is*, or does history read the way Git reads it out to you?

<sup>2</sup>This is, in effect, Git's answer to the philosophical question in footnote 1.  History reads the way Git reads it to you, but is *recorded* as the *real* history.  On cloning, Git clones the *real* history, and ignores the graft.  You can, subsequent to cloning, ask Git to copy grafts *too*, but that's not the default.

Besides this, you can run `git --no-replace-objects log` and see the real history, and when looking at grafted history, an optional decoration marks each graft, so that you can see it if you look closely.

Comment: Really thorough response on grafting, thank you! By efficiency I didn't mean cpu cycles to perform the git fix but rather the least amount of commands/steps to reach the outcome. Would definitely like to achieve a connected history and not change the hashes (which could otherwise have an adverse effect on other people sitting at specific hashes and branches on the project)