# How to prepare and apply multiple patches for the last N commits in git

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, git-apply

I need to create a patch file for the last N commits and apply them as separate commits to another branch. For N=3 I assume I have to do this:

> git diff HEAD~3 HEAD~2 >> diff1
>   git diff HEAD~2 HEAD~1 >> diff2
>   git diff HEAD~1 HEAD >> diff3

and then apply them on another branch respectively:

> git apply diff1
>   (push)
>   git apply diff2
>   (push)
>   git apply diff3

Is there any shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done with [git format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and [git am](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am), respectively.  From your example, try:

```
git format-patch HEAD~3
```

This will generate files `0001-commit-foo.patch`, `0002-commit-bar.patch`, `0003-commit-baz.patch`.  Then you can copy them to another repo and use `git am` to apply them:

```
git am *.patch
```

This will preserve the commits as you made them in the previous tree including commit messages, SHAs, and timestamps.

Comment: If anyone struggle with "fatal: could not open '*.patch' for reading: Invalid argument" error message from msysgit, here is why: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/1IT785Jf4Zo

Answer (score 1):

Try `git cherry-pick` commits to another branch (no need to create temporary patches). This questions answers how to cherry-pick multiple commits at a time: [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits)

Comment: I need the patch. The branches are on two different projects.

Comment: You can still cherry-pick between different repositories if you add the second repo as a remote to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned in a comment that you need the patches, because the branches are on different projects. That's not a problem. You can add a remote for the other project, and you can cherry-pick from it, even if they don't share a common history. Cherry-picking doesn't concern ancestry, it's just about replaying changes, just as you would with patches.

---

If for some reason cherry picking is really not an option for you (though I really doubt), you can use loops in Bash, for example:

```
for ((i = 3, d = 1; i > 0; i--, d++)); do ((j = i - 1)); git diff HEAD~$i HEAD~$j > diff$d; done
```

You can write a similar loop for the `git apply` commands.