# merge new github repo into remote

Tags: git, github, rational-team-concert

I am trying to merge commits from branch B to branch A.

```
branch A has commits a-c 
branch B has commits d-f BUT doesn't have commits a-c in it's commit history.
```

How can I get branch B's commits d-f to show in branch A after commit c.

I tried `git cherry-pick hashCommit` but I got a message saying

```
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git reset'
```

I also checked out this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits/12646996#12646996), but wasn't sure which Answer was suitable for me.

When I look in my github pages branch B, at the top it say branch B is x commits ahead of branch A

[image]

Also after doing the `cherry-pick`, when I type git log, the first commit shows

```
commit hashCommitNumber (HEAD -> branchB, origin/branchB, branchA)
```

I am currently checked out on branch B

Answer (score 0):

> What I did was I migrated the RTC histories from the last successful cut off date to the present date

It depends on how/where that migration was made: if it is in a new repo/new branch, then yes, a merge would be difficult (unrelated history)

A better practice is:

- having a local clone of your GitHub repository, set on the branch you want to update with RTC new changesets
- having a local RTC repository workspace (sandbox)
- [iterate on each changeset](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/121821/how-to-load-a-specific-change-set-to-sandbox) and update your sandbox
- use `git --work-tree=/path/to/sandbox add .` (done inside your local Git clone). That will detect any new/changed/removed file from sandbox compared to your current Git repository content
- commit, and repeat for the next changeset.

Comment: Would this have to be done manually for each changeset? There are hundreds of them. I think the purpose of using rtc2gitcli tool was so that it is automated, but this initializes a local git repository which I have to connect to remote, but that gave me the problems in OP

Comment: Then use rtc2git, then cherry-pick the commit from the new unrelated branch into your existing one.

Comment: Do you know how I can do that? I tried to cherry pick but it says the previous Cherry Pick is empty. I updated OP to explain what I have done.

Comment: @henhen You can cherry-pick a range of commits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309

Comment: yes, thats what I did first, but I got the following error
`error: empty commit set passed,
fatal: cherry-pick failed
`

Comment: @henhen the order of commits in the range matter, as explained in the link.

Comment: when I do this, should I be checked out on branch B or branch A? branch B is the branch with commits branch A does not have.

Comment: @hen A, meaning the destination branch, the one where you need to create commits