# Git cherry pick list of commits

Tags: git

I would like to merge into my branch only a specific list of commits `[A, C, E]`.

The solution I often see would be to do `git cherry-pick A^..E` but it would also commit `B`and `D` that I don't want. Is there a way to specify the exact list of commits I want ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits) specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47767118/989920)

Comment: Just `git cherry-pick A C E`

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more descriptive alternative to `cherry-pick` is  `git rebase -i BRANCH_TO_REBASE` which gives you the possibility to select interactively a specific list of commits.

Comment: Although this is true (and I also often use it for this purpose) you can't always cherry-pick through a rebase (especially between far away branches)